# Convert a JSON string to object in J2ME?

Tags: java, json, java-me, object, serialization

I've asked this before for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-string-to-object-in-java), but this applies specifically to J2ME.

Is there a way in J2ME to convert a string, such as:

```
{"name":"MyNode", "width":200, "height":100}
```

to an internal *Object* representation of the same, in one line of code?

---

The problem with such JSON libraries, is that they generate *JSONObjects* from strings, not plain *Objects*. My function requires an *Object*, so can I stuff down a *JSONObject* into it??

- Internal JSON classes such as [JSONObject](http://www.j2ee.me/developer/technicalArticles/javame/json-me/)
- [JSON-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *The problem with such JSON libraries,
>   is that they generate JSONObjects from
>   strings, not plain Objects. My
>   function requires an Object, so can I
>   stuff down a JSONObject into it??*

A "plain Object" (that is, an instance of the class `java.lang.Object`) cannot represent any state apart from its own identity.  So what you are asking for is impossible.

On the other hand, all Java classes are implicitly subtypes of `java.lang.Object`, so any function that takes an `Object` parameter can be called with a `JSONObject` instance as argument ... assuming that `JSONObject` is a concrete Java class.

Comment: Yea, what an idiot I've been. I must identify exactly which class my function needs. The docs say "Object" because they're not specific enough and so I was stupid enough just to retransmit that crap info. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) does what you want. It does take a little bit more than just one line for setting things up, etc, but I've used it before in projects and it's a very useful conversion library.

Comment: You can't use Google GSon in a J2ME project since it uses Java Reflections.