# J2ME, how to encode and decode Json?

Tags: json, rest, java-me

how to encode and decode Json in J2ME?

Comment: Have you tried [this code](https://meapplicationdevelopers.dev.java.net/source/browse/meapplicationdevelopers/demobox/mobileajax/lib/json/)? It's old, but I believe it should still work fine.

Comment: This is difficult to understand, especially for those who can't even use search engines...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a JSON string to object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encoding it you can easily do manually, but for encoding and decoding here is a tutorial to help you.

http://jimmod.com/blog/2010/03/java-me-j2me-json-implementation-tutorialsample/