# How to validate JSON object?

Tags: java, json, validation

I would like to validate incoming json object for correctness at the server side. Is there a standard / optimal way to do that? What is your approach of validation?

Comment: What server side language are you using?  A lot will depend on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice - deserialize the JSON and see if it breaks.  For example, if you're using C# on the server side, you can use the newfangled `DataContractJsonSerializer`, or do it the old way with the `JavaScriptSerializer` which is arguably much simpler.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
```

EDIT: And now that it's come out that you're using Java, of course my C# example is not going to work for you, but the concept is the same.  Stackoverflow already has some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java): [Convert a JSON string to object in Java ME?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know the way to convert json to java object. I would want to do quick generic validation on it ( to check whether its valid ) before converting it into java object.

Comment: @Harsha Validating the JSON text would mean parsing it to some extent. Therefor, for correct json text (which should outnumber invalid json by a large factor in any decent application) you will end up doing double parsing. Is that really worth it?

Comment: Many times you may want the validation to occur before the request hits the backend. In that case some sort of schema validation is in order.

Answer (score 3):

Decode it with a JSON library. If it successfully decodes using a library that follows the specifications then it's valid.

Comment: Yeah one of quickest way is to decode it into java object and see if it throws error while decoding. I want to do a generic validation on given json object without converting it into java object. I dont want to create java object just for validation. Any of your favorite json library / utility that would help me?