# Generate JSON for PHP

Tags: java, php, android, json, web-services

I'm generating a JSON thru PHP to integrate into an application for android, I do not know if it is correct as I am doing, because a lot do not know of PHP, JSON is generated without indentation and am having trouble reading in java, then wonder if it is correct, and if there is any example is welcome.

follows the code below:

```
<?php

 $modulos = array(
     "inicial" => array(
            "conteudo" => "A  é uma empresa especializada no desenvolvimento de
                    aplicativos móveis e sistemas para smartphones e tablets. ",
            //Não é o logotipo, é a imagem principal da primeira pag
            "imagem" => "http://.com.br/wp-content/uploads/logotipo.png"
                        ),// fim nó inicial

    "quemsomos" => array(
        //conteudo bem resumido, seria intereçante o usuario ter um local no site
        // para definir os textos e parametros mobile
        "conteudo" => "Desenvolve soluções móveis de acordo com a necessidade do cliente 
                       independentemente do segmento, exploramos as amplas possibilidades 
                       dos novos recursos em comunicação móvel para uso em Smartphones e Tablets."
                        ),//fim nó quem somos

    "produtos" => array(
        "produto" => array(
            "titulo" => "Aplicativo gloop",
            "descricao" => "Pacote completo, Web Site/App IOS/App Android",
            "imagem" => "http://site.holyis.com/sites/5/imagens/logo.png",
            "detalhes" => "link de JSON que contem dados dos detalhes do produto"
                        ),

        //para mais que um produto é só copiar o primeiro e incluir aqui
        "produto" => array(
            "titulo" => "Aplicativo gloop ",
            "descricao" => "Pacote completo, Web Site/App IOS/App Android",
            "imagem" => "http://site.holyis.com/sites/5/imagens/logo.png",
            "detalhes" => "link de JSON que contem dados dos detalhes do produto"
                            ),
                        ),//fim nó produtos

    "servicos" => array(
        "servico" => array(
            "titulo" => "Desenvolvimento mobile",
            "descricao" => "Atuamos no desenvolvimento de aplicações móveis para as 
                            plataformas IOS e Android usando seus próprios SDKs. Publicamos
                            sua aplicação nas lojas Apple Store e Google play.",
            "imagem" => "http://.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/android-iphone-sdk1.png"
                            ),
        //para mais que um servico é só copiar o primeiro e incluir aqui
        "servico" => array(
            "titulo" => "Implementação de idéias",
            "descricao" => "Teve uma idéia mas não tem conhecimento para implementa-la ? 
                            Entre em contato que temos toda estrutura para colocar em prática.",
            "imagem" => "http://.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ideia.png"
                            ),
                        ),//fim nó servicos


                );//fim nó pai

utf8_encode($modulos);
$json = json_encode($modulos);

echo $json;


?>
```

result:

> {"inicial":{"conteudo":"A \u00e9 uma empresa
>   especializada no desenvolvimento de\n\t\t\t\t\taplicativos m\u00f3veis
>   e sistemas para smartphones e tablets.
>   ","imagem":"http://.com.br/wp-content/uploads/logotipo.png"},"quemsomos":{"conteudo":"Desenvolve
>   solu\u00e7\u00f5es m\u00f3veis de acordo com a necessidade do cliente
>   \n\t\t\t\t\t independentemente do segmento, exploramos as amplas
>   possibilidades \n\t\t\t\t\t dos novos recursos em
>   comunica\u00e7\u00e3o m\u00f3vel para uso em Smartphones e
>   Tablets."},"produtos":{"produto":{"titulo":"Aplicativo gloop
>   ","descricao":"Pacote completo, Web Site/App IOS/App
>   Android","imagem":"http://site.holyis.com/sites/5/imagens/logo.png","detalhes":"link
>   de JSON que contem dados dos detalhes do
>   produto"}},"servicos":{"servico":{"titulo":"Implementa\u00e7\u00e3o de
>   id\u00e9ias","descricao":"Teve uma id\u00e9ia mas n\u00e3o tem
>   conhecimento para implementa-la ? \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tEntre em contato que
>   temos toda estrutura para colocar em
>   pr\u00e1tica.","imagem":"http://.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/ideia.png"}}}

Comment: It's valid. It's easy to check your syntax using jsonlint like the post below

Comment: Why do you think it is not correct? Which part of it makes you wonder?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate JSON object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100256/how-to-validate-json-object)

Comment: You really should have tried Google... http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct, in the future you can check for yourself using [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: This is more a comment like an answer.

Comment: JSON is valid, thanks for the reply, I only have one more doubt, there's something I can do to that JSON is displayed with the indentation instead of plain text without line breaks?

Comment: If you are working with PHP 5.4 or above you can use the second parameter to [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and pass it the constant JSON_PRETTY_PRINT

Answer (score 0):

http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ is another page where you can validate JSON.
It is correct.