# How to parse with GSON when identifier has space in name

Tags: java, android, json, gso

How to parse with GSON when file looks like this

```
{
    "Person Id":"test",
    "Last Name": "test",
    "First Name":"test"
}
```

I know to parse when names doesn't have space between, I create class like

```
class Person{
public String PersonId;
public String LastName;
public String FirstName;
}
```

but how to parse when identifier has space inside ? What to change in Person class ? ( I cannot change format of file ).

Comment: look at the end of this thread: http://groups.google.com/group/google-gson/tree/browse_frm/month/2010-05/e575bb65cdd30410?rnum=31&_done=/group/google-gson/browse_frm/month/2010-05?&pli=1

Comment: Use underscore to replace the space?

Comment: Your field identifiers use names that are contrary to Java coding conventions. Start identifiers with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to parse this JSON but I didn't use GSON to parse this. I'll share my code with you, kindly consider only as a supplementary solution to solve the issue:

```
String parse = "{\"Person Id\":\"test\",\"Last Name\": \"lname\",\"First Name\":\"fname\"}";
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject   =   new JSONObject(parse);
    String id = jsonObject.getString("Person Id");
    System.out.println("id="+id);
    System.out.println("lname="+jsonObject.getString("Last Name"));
    System.out.println("fname="+jsonObject.getString("First Name"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 40):

While still using GSON you can do this by adding an annotation.  For instance:

```
class Person{
    @SerializedName("Person Id") public String PersonId;
    @SerializedName("Last Name") public String LastName;
    @SerializedName("First Name") public String FirstName;
}
```

You can find more details in the GSON documentation:
https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-JSON-Field-Naming-Support