# Unable to convert JSON string to JAVA Object using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a `json` file in which I have saved a schedule for a particular channel. Now, I want to convert the `string` to a java object using gson. I know it is pretty trivial, but there is something I am confused about the structure of the string. This is the format of my JSON string:

```
{
  "date": "28022014",
  "channelName": "star-movies",
  "listOfShows": [
    {
      "showTitle": "Pirates of the Caribbean: The Curse of the Black Pearl",
      "showTime": "01:30:00",
      "showThumb": "http://tv.burrp.com/images/s/v/v/vv71wogh_644_4_140.jpg",
      "showDetails": {
        "IMDB Rating": "8.0/10",
        "Nominated For": "Bafta Film Award Best Performance by an Actor in 2004: Johnny Depp, Best Sound in 2004: Christopher Boyes; George Watters II, Best in Special Visual Effects: John Knoll; Hal T. Hickel",
        "Trivia": "The movie is inspired by, and takes its theme from, the popular Walt Disney theme park ride of the same name.",
        "Produced By": "Jerry Bruckheimer",
        "Directed By": "Gore Verbinski",
        "Show Type:": "Movie",
        "Followed By": "Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Man\u0027s Chest",
        "Written By": "Ted Elliott, Terry Rossio",
        "Language:": "English",
        "Repeats on:": "Sun, Feb 23 11:30PM Tue, Feb 25 7:00AM Wed, Feb 26 2:00PM",
        "Music By": "Klaus Badelt",
        "Release Date": "9 July 2003",
        "Cast": "Johnny Depp, Geoffrey Rush, Orlando Bloom, Keira Knightley, Jack Davenport",
        "Genre:": "Action/Adventure Sci-Fi/Fantasy",
        "Show Description": "The Governor\u0027s beautiful daughter Elizabeth (Keira Knightley) is kidnapped by the evil Captain Barbossa (Geoffrey Rush). At that point, Will Turner (Orlando Bloom), her would-be suitor, seeks the help of Captain Jack Sparrow (Johnny Depp), a notorious conman. But then, Jack has his own reasons for hunting down Barbossa and his crew. They have stolen Sparrow\u0027s ship, The Black Pearl."
      }
    },
    {
      "showTitle": "Fillers",
      "showTime": "03:30:00",
      "showThumb": "http://tv.burrp.com/images/s/e/i/eims7nmh_1fwv_1_75.jpg",
      "showDetails": {
        "Repeats on:": "Sat, Feb 22 1:29AM Mon, Feb 24 3:30AM Tue, Feb 25 2:30AM",
        "Language:": "English",
        "Show Type:": "Promo/Filler",
        "Show Description": "It\u0027s a series featuring film based program."
      }
    },
    ....
    ...
  }]
 }
```

This is the structure of classes that I have come up with:

```
public class ChannelSchedule {

    private String date;
    private String channelName;
    private List<Show> listOfShows;
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getChannelName() {
        return channelName;
    }
    public void setChannelName(String channelName) {
        this.channelName = channelName;
    }
    public List<Show> getListOfShows() {
        return listOfShows;
    }
    public void setListOfShows(List<Show> listOfShows) {
        this.listOfShows = listOfShows;
    }
}



 public class Show {

    private String showTitle;
    private String showTime;
    private String showThumb;

    public String getShowThumb() {
        return showThumb;
    }
    public void setShowThumb(String showThumb) {
        this.showThumb = showThumb;
    }
    public String getShowTitle() {
        return showTitle;
    }
    public void setShowTitle(String showTitle) {
        this.showTitle = showTitle;
    }
    public String getShowTime() {
        return showTime;
    }
    public void setShowTime(String showTime) {
        this.showTime = showTime;
    }

}
```

I am unable to figure out how to objectify `showDetails` in a list? As it has space in between its key value pairs...? Am I missing something here? Or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Are you having trouble modeling the JSON in Java, or are you getting some error when trying to deserialize? If you're asking about modeling, I'd suggest using an unstructured `Map` for that part, since it looks like it's variable key-value pairs.

Comment: Yes, modelling it is, how would `maps` work in this case?

Comment: ..and would `gson` support `maps`?

Comment: [How to parse with GSON when identifier has space in name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15907855/1212960)

Comment: Do you know how to use Java `Map`s? They're a pretty basic part of the standard library; if you're not familiar with them, [read the docs here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). You'd want to declare `Map<String,String> showDetails`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse with GSON when identifier has space in name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963553/how-to-parse-with-gson-when-identifier-has-space-in-name)

Comment: @chrylis you are right. Using `Map<String, String> showDetails` solved it for me, but I used `jackson` library for `JSON` object mapping for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options;

It looks like `showDetails` can have a number of different things in it. You *could* map out every possible one if you know what they are:

```
public class ShowDetails {

    @SerializedName("IMDB Rating")
    String imdbRating;
    @SerializedName("Repeats on:")
    String repeatsOn;
    // etc , etc

}
```

And then add that to your `Show` class:

```
...
ShowDetails showDetails;
...
```

But that may be a bit insane, depending on how many things can be there, or if you don't know what all the possibilities are. Option B is simpler, use a `Map<String, String>`:

```
public class Show {

    private String showTitle;
    private String showTime;
    private String showThumb;
    private Map<String, String> showDetails;
    // ...
}
```

The key/value pairs in your JSON will be put in the map as ... key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

You Model ShowDetails as a different class and have a ShowDetails attribute in your Show class. To refer to the attributes with spaces and colon symbols you use anotations @"key".

Comment: Doesn't work in this case because that object is a random assortment of trivia about the show. I think a `Map<String,String>` is the best he'll get.