# How to parse with GSON when identifier has space in name and Turkish Char

Tags: java, gson

How can i parse this json with GSON to my model?

Thanks for help.

{
"Kod":"XU100",
"Son Değer":"83.947",
"En Düşük":"83.947",
"En Yüksek":"86.355"
},

Comment: maybe duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963553/how-to-parse-with-gson-when-identifier-has-space-in-name

Comment: i try it but continue problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be like:

```
@SerializedName("Kod")
private String kod;

@SerializedName("Son Değer")
private String sonDeger;

@SerializedName("En Düşük")
private String enDusuk;

@SerializedName("En Yüksek")
private String enYuksek;

//Getters and Setters
```

And then:

```
YourClass yourClass = gson.fromJson(json, YourClass.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Main problem is from android studio encoding. i change to iso and fixed my problem