# Cannot convert json file to list of objects using gson API caused by an illegal attribute's name

Tags: java, json, gson

*Consider this json file `example.json`*

```
[
  {
    "permalink": "c8635076fa371e7642e6e284cc9b60dc",
    "pecas": {
      "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-": {
        "id": "6a082df27f9fe4be184d7222b79c2f8a",
        "path": "p-554ba68ce4b04befa5148ae4/conteudo/08039a5f3ea1924ed7950bc0caf434a2.swf",
        "nome": "Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-.swf",
        "pathOriginal": "1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-.swf",
        "imagem": "p-554ba68ce4b04befa5148ae4/conteudo/d8c6b07bebf7df2c894c6b6ddaa35bbb.gif"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

*In order to convert this json file to a list of objects, I have created these classes but I have encountered a problem caused by an illegal attribute's name*

Identifier class: (Here all attributes have a correct name)

```
class Identifier {
    String id;
    String path;
    String nome;
    String pathOriginal;
    String imagem;
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[ " + id + " , " + path + " , " + nome + " , " + pathOriginal
                + " , " + imagem + " ]";
    }
    // getters, setters,...
}
```

Pecas class: (**Here is the problem because of this variable name `1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-`**)

```
class Pecas {
    Identifier 1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-;
// Of course this is will not compile
// getters, setters, toString..
}
```

Data class: (no problem here)

```
class Data {
    String permalink;
    Pecas pecas;
    // getters, setters, toString...
}
```

As I know so far, in order to use `Gson API` to convert this json file to a list of `Data` objects, all attributes in the above nested classes must be named according to json file'fields (like what i did above).

So here comes my question: Am i able to change this illegal attribute name `1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-` to another one `identifier` so that i can do this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Data> list = gson.fromJson(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
        "example.json")), new TypeToken<List<Data>>() {
}.getType());

Identifier id = list.get(0).getPecas().getIdentifier();
System.out.println(id);
```

*And the output will be*

```
[ 6a082df27f9fe4be184d7222b79c2f8a , p-554ba68ce4b04befa5148ae4/conteudo/08039a5f3ea1924ed7950bc0caf434a2.swf , Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-.swf , 1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-.swf , p-554ba68ce4b04befa5148ae4/conteudo/d8c6b07bebf7df2c894c6b6ddaa35bbb.gif ]
```

Or maybe there is another solution? (like use of `annotation` or something like that...)

**Note:** I cannot change anything from the json file.

Comment: @downvoter any comments?

Comment: *Note: I cannot change anything from the json file.* then you can not use that JSON file with Java then.

Comment: refer to [How to parse with GSON when identifier has space in name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963553/how-to-parse-with-gson-when-identifier-has-space-in-name#answer-15907855)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing an assist from [How to parse with GSON when identifier has space in name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963553/how-to-parse-with-gson-when-identifier-has-space-in-name#answer-15907855). I'm not very familiar with Gson, but something like this should do the trick. I've tested this much and it works:

**class:**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
public class Identifier {
     @SerializedName("1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-") public String key;
}
```

**test method:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{'1401 Pecas Midia Grafica_v2/Whirlpool_LinhaBranca_Positivo_CanaisdeAfinidade_SuperBanner_-':'some value'}";
    Identifier id = new Gson().fromJson(json, Identifier.class);
    System.out.println(id.key);
}
```

Comment: Woow super genuis +1 and accepted answer, It works perfectly. But I still can't figure out why they downvoted my question. Is it that bad and non-constructive?

Comment: Personally, the problem I had with your question was that I found your collection of work fairly incomprehensible. However, it was clear to me what problem you were having and where you were having it. So, I reduced it to the version I presented you with. I did not down vote you, just FYI.

Comment: Since you have your solution now, just leave it the way it is. it's not worth spending even more time on it. In the future, consider showing only the most relevant piece of code you are having a problem with. The question I linked to is a good example of this.

Comment: **this will only work for this one instance, this is not a valid solution for any other file with any other data in it, this is a non-answer because the data for a specific instance is hard coded into the annotation**