# How to convert this JSON to object in JAVA android?

Tags: java, android, json

How to convert this JSON to an object?

[image]

Comment: Would you please provide the code that you have tried?

Comment: search "json to java object" on the internet. I have personally used "http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/" this site. If you are using a Gson converter tick that option, change the package name, choose a file name, check source type->JSON. Thats it then download the files and use

Comment: Please include what you started so far so that we can check. You may start to look for Gson on how to use it and check Gson Serializers.

Comment: Please follow the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079505/converting-json-string-to-java-object

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Gson`,

> Gson a Java serialization/deserialization library to convert Java
>   Objects into JSON and back

First u should put this code lines on gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
 }
```

If you use maven add as below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.6</version>
 </dependency>
```

And finally after take json string,

```
String json = "here your json string";

Gson gson = new Gson();

YOURCLASS yourclass = gson.fromJson(json, YOURCLASS.class);
```

[Another using examples here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/gson.html)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using GSON trying to extract value for each JSON key and use the below "smart" method of automatic JSON to Java object generator.

What you exactly require is POJO. Additionally, you wouldn't want to write down the java program for a huge JSON object, do you?

The site to convert JSON string to java data class: [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Tutorial to convert JSON to Java Data class using the above site: [Jackson 2 – Convert Java Object to / from JSON](https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-2-convert-java-object-to-from-json/)

As an example my JSON is:

```
{
   "name":"John",
   "age":30,
   "cars":[ [1, "Ford"], [2, "BMW"], [3, "Fiat"] ]
}
```

The generated "data" class for the above JSON is:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "name",
    "age",
    "cars"
})

public class Example {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("age")
    public int age;

    @JsonProperty("cars")
    public List<List<Integer>> cars = null;

}
```

And then use the above class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/* .... */

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Example example;

try {
    example = mapper.readValue(jsonString.toString(), Example.class);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// To get name
System.out.println(example.name);
```

Include *jackson* in *gradle*:

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'
```

If you are facing issues exclude `META-INF/LICENSE` in the android tag in the *gradle* file to avoid dup license file error in Android studio:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```

Just be sure to use proper configuration for the [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) website, my configurations are:

[image: Configuration screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**In addition to Gson library (@errorau answer), you can use java JSONObject class.**

```java
String jsonstr = "{\"age\":18, \"name\": \"Mr. Bean\", \"data\":[\"A\",\"B\"]}"
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
```

To get values from JSONObject, use function `getString`, `getInt`, `getJSONArray` etc.

```java
String name = json.getString("name");  // output: Mr. Bean
int age = json.getInt("age");  // output: 18

JSONArray stringArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(stringArray.getString(i));  // output: A, B
```

or if you have nested json. Use `getJSONObject` function

```
String jsonstr = "{\"data\":{\"name\": \"Mr. Bean\"}}"
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstr);
JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
String name = data.getString("name")  // output: Mr. Bean
```