# Create an array of JSON Objects in Java

Tags: java, json

I have a CSV file which has 10 columns and multiple rows. I want to store each row in a JSON object. For example the file would look like below :

```
Name, Age, Address..........and other columns
ABCD, 23 , HOME.............and other columns
```

So I want it to be stored in a JSON object as `{"Name":"ABC" ,"Age":"23", "Address":"HOME"}`

Now, since there will be multiple rows, how do I create an array of JSON objects and store each row in an object? How do I retrieve or print each row too from the JSON objects?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

JSON Object should create something like this:-

```
{'UserDetails': [{'Name':'ABC', 'Age':'44', 'Address':'HOME'}, 
                 {'Name':'DEF','Age':'23', 'Address':'HOME'}]
                 .....
                 .....
}
```

To Retrieve:-

```
JSONObject userDet = new JSONObject(user_info);
JSONArray userDetJson = userDet.getJSONArray("UserDetails");
```

Refer some more information [Convert a JSON string to object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java), [Creating & Parsing JSON data with Java Servlet/Struts/JSP](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/02/creating-parsing-json-data-with-java-servlet-struts-jsp-json.html) and **[JSON-lib: Snippets](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/snippets.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Create object which will hold 10 parameters

```
public class LineObject implements Serializable {
   private String name;
   private int age;
   private String address;
   //...
   // get,set,equals,hashcode
}
```

then parse CSV file and each line save to `LineObject`. By parsing whole file you'll get `List<LineObject>`. Then serialize this to JSON using e.g. [Jackson JSON processor](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

To get object from JSON, use again Jackson JSON processor for deserialization.