# json to java object convertion

Tags: java, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a JSON string to object in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java)

Below is my json structure .I want to convert it to java object .Can any help me to parse this jason object

```
{"response":{"@id":"","":{"":[{"":"","":"","":"","":"","":"","":"","":"","":"","":"","":""},{},{},{},.....{}]}}}

Thanks
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? I generally start with the innermost entry and work outwards.

Comment: I've lost count how many times this exact same question has been asked `*sigh*`

Answer (score 0):

That is not well-formed JSON.  For a start, you have multiple attributes with the same name.  There's no Java JSON library that could represent that.