# How to parse JSON to list of strings?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a json file.

```
{
    "data" : [
        "my/path/old",
        "my/path/new"
    ]
}
```

I need to conver it to ArrayList of String. How to do it using Jackson library?

UPD:

My code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();        
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(FileReader.class.getResourceAsStream(file)));

List<String> list = (ArrayList) gson.fromJson(reader, ArrayList.class);

for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

And my exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 column 1
```

My new update

UPD2:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type list = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(FileReader.class.getResourceAsStream(file)));
List<String> s = gson.fromJson(reader, list);
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert the following json string to java object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object)

Comment: They using GSON and JSR 353.

Comment: Look at the first answer.

Comment: The correct answer is using `jackson` @Flavio

Comment: But I don't need to create an entity. I need just list of strings.

Comment: Your JSON is an object, not an array. There's no obvious way to convert it to a `List`. Do you want the array named `data`?

Comment: I updated my question and added some code.

Comment: And I have new update which does't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've tagged Jackson but are using Gson in your example. I'm going to go with Jackson

```
String json = "{\"data\":[\"my/path/old\",\"my/path/new\"]}"; // or wherever you're getting it from
```

Create your `ObjectMapper`

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

Read the JSON String as a tree. Since we know it's an object, you can cast the `JsonNode` to an `ObjectNode`.

```
ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode)mapper.readTree(json);
```

Get the `JsonNode` named `data`

```
JsonNode arrayNode = node.get("data");
```

Parse it into an `ArrayList<String>`

```
ArrayList<String> data = mapper.readValue(arrayNode.traverse(), new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>(){});
```

Printing it

```
System.out.println(data);
```

gives

```
[my/path/old, my/path/new]
```

Comment: @Flavio Are you sure your JSON is well formed? You might want to convert it to a `String` and print it out before passing it to your `ObjectMapper`. Also I was using Jackson 2. You might wish to upgrade.