# After converting an object to a String, how can I get the object back from the string again?

Tags: java, android, string, object, casting

I was creating a simple android application in which I am converting an object to `String`. How can I re-convert the object from the `string`?

I am converting my object to String using the following line of code.

```
String convertedString = object.toString();
```

Comment: You need to implement your own method in the class of your object.

Comment: You can hold the object with other variable before string converting method then you have object in seperate.

Comment: Why would you want to convert an object to a string and back? Are you doing it to store the object in a file? What is the class of the object?

Answer (score 0):

You can't**, because that is not what the toString method is for. It's used to make a readable representation of your Object, but it's not meant for saving and later reloading.

What you are looking for instead is Serialization. See this tutorial here to get started:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

** Technically you *could*, but you *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

- Java Serialization
- Using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Goals-for-Gson) library (more simple), remember the the purpose of this lib is to convert simply json to object and viceversa when working with REST services.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use Serialization to convert object to string and vise versa:

```
 String serializedObject = "";

 // serialize the object
 try {
     ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     ObjectOutputStream so = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
     so.writeObject(myObject);
     so.flush();
     serializedObject = bo.toString();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e);
 }

 // deserialize the object
 try {
     byte b[] = serializedObject.getBytes(); 
     ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
     ObjectInputStream si = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
     MyObject obj = (MyObject) si.readObject();
 } catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println(e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Java **Serialization** for doing same.

Go with below link for better understand how to convert java object.
Ex.  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/serialization-in-java/

Also You can go with this link:

[How to convert the following json string to java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object)