# Can't cast json object properly

Tags: java, json

I have  json  data  like this :

```
 {\"FinalResult\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":11,\\\"organizationNameGE\\\":\\\"erer\\\",\\\"organizationNameEN\\\":\\\"rerer\\\",\\\"cardNumber\\\":\\\"3434343\\\",\\\"startDate\\\":\\\"02/04/2018\\\",\\\"period\\\":1,\\\"endDate\\\":\\\"02/06/2018\\\",\\\"priority\\\":\\\"middle
 important\\\",\\\"$$hashKey\\\":\\\"0QI\\\"}]\"}
```

and  i  want  to  get  json array  items  and  use  it  in my  code , here  is my  java  code:

```
 JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
 JSONObject jsonObjectR= null;

 try {
     //jsonObjectR = (JSONObject) parser.parse("{\"FinalResult\":\"[{\\\"id\\\":11,\\\"organizationNameGE\\\":\\\"erer\\\",\\\"organizationNameEN\\\":\\\"rerer\\\",\\\"cardNumber\\\":\\\"3434343\\\",\\\"startDate\\\":\\\"02/04/2018\\\",\\\"period\\\":1,\\\"endDate\\\":\\\"02/06/2018\\\",\\\"priority\\\":\\\"middle important\\\",\\\"$$hashKey\\\":\\\"0QI\\\"}]\"}");
     jsonObjectR=(JSONObject) parser.parse(new String(msg));
 } catch (ParseException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
 }

 JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObjectR.get("FinalResult");
 JSONArray json1 = jsonArray;
Sustem.out.println(json1 [0].priority)
```

it  throws   exception  like this:

```
 org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject
```

i  have  replaced `org.json.simple.JSONObject`  this  import  by  `org.json.JSONObject`  but this  hasn't  change  anything, what  should  i   add  to  make  this  task  properly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object this may help you.

Comment: http://www.java67.com/2016/10/3-ways-to-convert-string-to-json-object-in-java.html it tells you how to convert string to json.