# How to parse complex nested json data

Tags: java, android, json

I am working on android application which shows the railways available in two stations.So, I am fetching the railway data from railwayapi to show information on android app.But I am not able to convert that JSON data.I am also having difficulties in creating object class for that. so, I need a help to convert that data.Any help will be appreciated.

I am giving the JSON data below,

```
{
    "debit": 1,
        "total": 3,
        "response_code": 200,
        "trains": [
    {
        "days": [
        {
            "code": "MON",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "TUE",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "WED",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "THU",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "FRI",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "SAT",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "SUN",
                "runs": "Y"
        }
        ],
        "number": "11030",
            "dest_arrival_time": "20:05",
            "src_departure_time": "07:55",
            "classes": [
        {
            "name": "FIRST CLASS",
                "code": "FC"
        },
        {
            "name": "SECOND SEATING",
                "code": "2S"
        },
        {
            "name": "AC CHAIR CAR",
                "code": "CC"
        },
        {
            "name": "SLEEPER CLASS",
                "code": "SL"
        },
        {
            "name": "FIRST AC",
                "code": "1A"
        },
        {
            "name": "THIRD AC",
                "code": "3A"
        },
        {
            "name": "SECOND AC",
                "code": "2A"
        },
        {
            "name": "3rd AC ECONOMY",
                "code": "3E"
        }
        ],
        "name": "KOYNA EXPRESS",
            "to_station": {
        "name": "C SHIVAJI MAHARAJ T",
                "code": "CSMT",
                "lng": 72.87033,
                "lat": 19.054346
    },
        "from_station": {
        "name": "KOLHAPUR",
                "code": "KOP",
                "lng": 74.24053,
                "lat": 16.70284
    },
        "travel_time": "12:10"
    },
    {
        "days": [
        {
            "code": "MON",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "TUE",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "WED",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "THU",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "FRI",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "SAT",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "SUN",
                "runs": "Y"
        }
        ],
        "number": "17412",
            "dest_arrival_time": "07:25",
            "src_departure_time": "20:30",
            "classes": [
        {
            "name": "FIRST CLASS",
                "code": "FC"
        },
        {
            "name": "SECOND SEATING",
                "code": "2S"
        },
        {
            "name": "AC CHAIR CAR",
                "code": "CC"
        },
        {
            "name": "SLEEPER CLASS",
                "code": "SL"
        },
        {
            "name": "FIRST AC",
                "code": "1A"
        },
        {
            "name": "THIRD AC",
                "code": "3A"
        },
        {
            "name": "SECOND AC",
                "code": "2A"
        },
        {
            "name": "3rd AC ECONOMY",
                "code": "3E"
        }
        ],
        "name": "MAHALAXMI EXP",
            "to_station": {
        "name": "C SHIVAJI MAHARAJ T",
                "code": "CSMT",
                "lng": 72.87033,
                "lat": 19.054346
    },
        "from_station": {
        "name": "KOLHAPUR",
                "code": "KOP",
                "lng": 74.24053,
                "lat": 16.70284
    },
        "travel_time": "10:55"
    },
    {
        "days": [
        {
            "code": "MON",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "TUE",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "WED",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "THU",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "FRI",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "SAT",
                "runs": "Y"
        },
        {
            "code": "SUN",
                "runs": "Y"
        }
        ],
        "number": "11024",
            "dest_arrival_time": "11:50",
            "src_departure_time": "22:50",
            "classes": [
        {
            "name": "FIRST CLASS",
                "code": "FC"
        },
        {
            "name": "SECOND SEATING",
                "code": "2S"
        },
        {
            "name": "AC CHAIR CAR",
                "code": "CC"
        },
        {
            "name": "SLEEPER CLASS",
                "code": "SL"
        },
        {
            "name": "FIRST AC",
                "code": "1A"
        },
        {
            "name": "THIRD AC",
                "code": "3A"
        },
        {
            "name": "SECOND AC",
                "code": "2A"
        },
        {
            "name": "3rd AC ECONOMY",
                "code": "3E"
        }
        ],
        "name": "SAHYADRI EXP",
            "to_station": {
        "name": "C SHIVAJI MAHARAJ T",
                "code": "CSMT",
                "lng": 72.87033,
                "lat": 19.054346
    },
        "from_station": {
        "name": "KOLHAPUR",
                "code": "KOP",
                "lng": 74.24053,
                "lat": 16.70284
    },
        "travel_time": "13:00"
    }
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for coverting json to PoJo and learn how to use gson - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the following json string to java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object)

Comment: use http://jsoneditoronline.org/ to see json in simple way and then you can get it done

Comment: Use this https://www.site24x7.com/tools/json-to-java.html to get the appropriate Java model class for your json. Now add Gson to your build the gradle. And then YourModelClassName obj=new Gson().fromJson(jsonString,YourModelClassName.class); will give you the appropriate data

Comment: Thaks Jobin Lawrance. I got the all Pojo classes, now I can easily process that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read [google Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) for parsing the Json response.
And for converting Json response to POJO class you need to see [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Comment: Thanks Hitesh Sarsava, This helped me lot.

Comment: your Welcome buddy.. @minfo

Answer (score 0):

There is a no way without parsing a response you got a data but you get that by using different techniques.

You can try using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) , [Gson1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)