# How to convert swagger JSON objects into Java class objects

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy, eclipse-plugin

Sorry for my naive question, I am looking for some tools that would automatically convert JSON objects (that are generated in swagger UI) to a Java class objects in Eclipse.

Are there any such tools or plugins that can integrate swagger code with Eclipse Java and Groovy Grails framework. It would save a lot of time by not rewriting a huge amount of Java code every time when I want to change something in JSON objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the following json string to java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `autorest` tool to generate code and models. It supports multiple languages including Java. Here is the github repository [autorest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest)

Just follow simple steps-

1. npm install -g autorest
2. autorest --input-file=https://******url******/swagger/v1/swagger.json --java --namespace=****namespace*****

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Gson](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html) Library in java.

Answer (score 0):

You could use that or Groovys JSONsluprer but I depending on what you're trying to achieve it might just be easiest if you have a swagger to start with swagger codegen https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen tools and have it make those for you. If not you can always look to investigate how they did it.