# Remove double quotes from JSON String

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've below JSON string:

```
{ "students" : "[  {\"studentId\" : \"A1\",\"studentNumber\" 
 : \"287\",\"studentType\" : \"FullTime\"} ]"  }
```

In order to deserialize this string in java object, I've to remove \ which can be done using string replace method. Apart from that there are double quotes also just before [ and after ]. how do I remove these double quotes or allow them while deserializeing using Jackson.

Comment: What if there is a data in any field containing a backslash like: `studentNumber: 2016\287` ? Still will you string replace?

Comment: use JSON parsing instead. It should create the object from the json string. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: There won't be any data with backslash. main concern here is " before [ and after ].

Comment: Answer of this question will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `"[` with `[` and `]"` with `]`

`json = json.replaceAll("\"\\[","[");`
       `json = json.replaceAll("\\]\"", "]");`

Comment: This is working fine. Just one question.. why do we add \\ before [ and ].

Comment: This is a hack that will likely break for nontrivial cases. I suspect the deserialized data will be wrong if anything in the student-objects contains json-escaped characters (e.g. quotes `"`, which will be doubly escaped) or `"[` or `"]`.

Comment: This should not have been the accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to do it yourself, jackson will take care of it. Create a pojo class Student and you can write something like below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Student student = mapper.readValue(responseBody, Student.class);
```

Comment: I did the same thing but because of extra \ and quotes before [ and after ] it's giving error. I removed \ using replace method but not able to remove quotes before [ and after ].

Comment: Below string works fine with my code: { "students" : [  {"studentId" : "A1","studentNumber" 
 : "287","studentType" : "FullTime"} ]  }

Answer (score 0):

Like `ObjectMapper`, we also may use `Gson`  for same purpose.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
gson.fromJson(responseBody, Student.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringTypeSerializationAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {


public String read(JsonReader reader) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

public void write(JsonWriter writer, String value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null) {
        writer.nullValue();
        return;
    }
    writer.jsonValue(value);
}
```

}

above removes quotes from strings using GSON string adapter