# How can I store googlesheet api response to an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, rest, google-sheets-api, httpsurlconnection

```
    public static String getsheetdata() throws IOException {

    String name = null;
    String email = null;
    String phone = null;
    String fin = null;
    String address = null;
    String car_registraion = null;
    String question = null;
    String pin = null;
    String car_registraion_date = null;

     String url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1BH-e3-XSZ9LjsQqELjZLpZbnB4DmIhrPy2VDAZsP9KM/values/lead!A2:J2?key=AIzaSyDJRy73ru1BSLFCb9nknUF8SlZd4LxwJAc";

     URL obj = new URL(url);
     HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
     // optional default is GET
     con.setRequestMethod("GET");
     //add request header
     con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-US) AppleWebKit/532.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.249.0 Safari/532.5");

     int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
     System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
     System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
     String inputLine;
     StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
     while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
     }
     in.close();

     System.out.println(response.toString());
     //Read JSON response and print
     JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());


    return inputLine;

}
```

I am getting following  response

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL : https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1BH-e3-XSZ9LjsQqELjZLpZbnB4DmIhrPy2VDAZsP9KM/values/lead!A2:J2?key=AIzaSyDJRy73ru1BSLFCb9nknUF8SlZd4LxwJAc
Response Code : 200
{  "range": "lead!A2:J2",  "majorDimension": "ROWS",  "values": [    [      "Lead Data Set 1 -  Normal FOC Lead",      "Bhupendra",      "bhupendra+283273@abc.com",      "2389432432",      "90909892098988771",      "Street123, Berlin",      "1289243424321",      "no comments",      "10115",      "12 / 12 / 2017"    ]  ]}
```

I need to fill the response data in following variables .

```
String name = null;
String email = null;
String phone = null;
String fin = null;
String address = null;
String car_registraion = null;
String question = null;
String pin = null;
String car_registraion_date = null;
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me on it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert the following json string to java object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any JSON to Java unmarshalling library to convert the JSON to Java object. Check [options and examples](https://www.baeldung.com/java-json)

Answer (score 0):

Create `JSONObject` of the response string you are getting and then extract `values` fields from `JSONObject` as `JSONArray` and then traverse through that JSONArray to get list of your object.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Hiren's answer, you can try (using `org.json`):

```
     JSONObject myResponse = new JSONObject(response.toString());
     JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) myResponse.get("values");
     JSONArray requiredValues = jsonArr.getJSONArray(0);
     String[] values = new String[requiredValues.length()];

     for (int i = 0; i < requiredValues.length(); i++) {
        values[i] = requiredValues.getString(i);
     }
```

Now the `"values"` part of response will be stored in `String[] values`

```
    for (int j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
         System.out.println(values[j]);
    }
```

This will print 
`Lead Data Set 1 -  Normal FOC Lead
Bhupendra
bhupendra+283273@abc.com
2389432432
90909892098988771
Street123, Berlin
1289243424321
no comments
10115
12 / 12 / 2017`

You can assign it accordingly. Hope it helps.