# how to take json data in java map or array

Tags: java, json

I have the following data as json and I want to take it in java

```
"endPoints": {
                "northAmerica": "https://ad-api.com",
                "europe": "https://ad-api-eu.com",
                "farEast": "https://ad-api-fe.com"
            }
```

I have tried the below code but not working.

```
Map<String, Object> endPoints = objectMapper.readValue(JsonParser
                    .parseString(additionalInfo().get("endPoints").toString())
                    .getAsJsonObject(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
                    });
```

anyone can help me how to do it?

Comment: How to do what?

Comment: how to take the json data in java in a convenient way

Comment: Please, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10324007/11984002

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make your data is a valid json format,then you can use [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) to do it

```
public static void testJsonConvert() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String data = "{\n" +
            "    \"endPoints\":{\n" +
            "        \"northAmerica\":\"https://ad-api.com\",\n" +
            "        \"europe\":\"https://ad-api-eu.com\",\n" +
            "        \"farEast\":\"https://ad-api-fe.com\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "}";
    Map<String, Object> map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(data, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: I'm getting "{northAmerica=https://ad-api.com, europe=https://ad-api-eu.com, farEast=https://ad-api-eu.com}"
I've used "String endpoints = additionalInfo().get("endPoints").toString();"
The String data you told me, is there any way to do it or do I have to do It manually?

Comment: @Kunaal you need to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

Any JSON string can be mapped to HashMap data structure as Key and Value pair.

There is an answer already in the thread.

But If you want a map of endpoints, like North America & Europe, you need to go a level deeper.

[ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) from [Jackson Core library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) will help.

First, get a HashMap of the data, then again get the endpoint from the HashMap.

```
String data = "{\n" +
    "    \"endPoints\":{\n" +
    "        \"northAmerica\":\"https://ad-api.com\",\n" +
    "        \"europe\":\"https://ad-api-eu.com\",\n" +
    "        \"farEast\":\"https://ad-api-fe.com\"\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(data, HashMap.class);
Map<String, Object> endPointMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("endPoints");
System.out.println(endPointMap);
```

result:

`{northAmerica=https://ad-api.com, europe=https://ad-api-eu.com, farEast=https://ad-api-fe.com}`

Comment: okay I'll try it