# how parse array in jsonObject?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSONObject, how do I parse the array (registrys) and take its element 0?

```
{
  "extendedResponseMessages": null,
  "responseBody": {
    "data": {
      "uid": "8ytythc5-cfhghg43-4ad0-a2hgd0-8ddhghg77",
      "pay": 1000,
      "name": "alex",
      "registrys": [],
      "status": "ACTIVE"
    },
```

Comment: Please give more context. If you need just a single string you can parse the json as string and find the corresponding part within it otherwise you need to convert your json document to a corresponding object using some libraries like Jackson or Gson

Comment: this is already an object, but it is necessary to take and pull only the zero element of the array from this object

Comment: I meant a corresponding Java object representation, basically a class defining the same structure as the json document. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308452/how-to-convert-the-following-json-string-to-java-object)