# Parse JSON without a particular standard structure into a Map or Java Object

Tags: java, json

It will be great if I can map the json to a Java object but the structure is pretty weird, it is different for all the json I am trying to parse. eg categories and topics can have different. How I can map it to a Java object, or any other suggestion??

`"name":"url",`
`"categories":`
`{`
`"249":{"catID":"249","score":33.43533451973102},`
`"34":{"catID":"34","score":3.0000000447034836},`
`.,.,so on`
`},`
`"topics":{`
`"DSLR":{"weight":1.6690950917579026,"noun":1},`
`"illuminated":{"weight":7.6470197510265105,"noun":0},`
`.`
`.so on`
`}}`

Comment: Take a look at this: [How to convert arbitrary JSON into a usable structure in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368619/how-to-convert-arbitrary-json-into-a-usable-structure-in-java/10369166#10369166)

Comment: Here is the output from GSON library:

    topics/{DSLR={weight=1.6690950917579026, noun=1}, illuminated={weight=7.6470197510265105, noun=0}, }

How can I now represent it in a JAVA object, considering multiple categories and topics
source/high
categories/{2_249={categoryID=249, taxID=2, score=33.43533451973102},...}

Answer (score 1):

Can you at least count on the JSON representation being consistent for each type of response / object mapping? If so, you can use the Google GSON library, and create a custom deserializer to handle the non-standard JSON representation.  Here is a link to the project:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

and to the user guide on how to create custom serializers / deserializers:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Comment: I tried your suggestion and implemented a GSON way to parse the JSON

this is the output
    topics/{DSLR={weight=1.6690950917579026, noun=1}, illuminated={weight=7.6470197510265105, noun=0}, }
source/high
categories/{2_249={categoryID=249, taxID=2, score=33.43533451973102},...}

How can I now represent this in a JAVA object?

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for that: org.json . To parse a JSONObject from a String, you say:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(string);
```

However, if the string represents an array instead of a map, use:

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(string);
```