# creating Hashmap from a JSON String

Tags: java, android, json, hashmap

creating a hashmap from a json string in java?

I have json string like `{"phonetype":"N95","cat":"WP"}` and want to convert into a standard Hashmap.

How can i do it?

Comment: Use a JSON library such as Jackson, for instance (see `JsonNode`)

Comment: Have a look at this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368619/how-to-convert-arbitrary-json-into-a-usable-structure-in-java

Comment: Handles nested and complex objects : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51121461/6665568

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Parse the JSONObject and create HashMap

```
public static void jsonToMap(String t) throws JSONException {

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
        Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

        while( keys.hasNext() ){
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            String value = jObject.getString(key); 
            map.put(key, value);

        }

        System.out.println("json : "+jObject);
        System.out.println("map : "+map);
    }
```

Tested output:

```
json : {"phonetype":"N95","cat":"WP"}
map : {cat=WP, phonetype=N95}
```

Comment: Please specify what library you are using, JSONObject from json-simple doesn't have methods `keys()` or `getString()`

Comment: @VinothkumarArputharaj When i convert a similar json string to JSONObject , its converted in random order.How can i convert a json string to json obects in same order??

Comment: HashMaps are not ordered: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: You can use Gson library

Answer (score 56):

You can use Google's Gson library to convert json to Hashmap. Try below code

```
String jsonString = "Your JSON string";
HashMap<String,String> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: Was looking for this. Thanks. Can you explain `TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType()`

Answer (score 20):

```
public class JsonMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}";
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            //convert JSON string to Map
            map = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {});
            System.out.println(map);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{phonetype=N95, cat=WP}
```

You can see this link it's helpful http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: `org.codehaus.jackson`? Still using Jackson 1.9.x? ;)

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library

```
Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.getType();
new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Answer (score 5):

This is simple operation no need to use any external library.

**You can use this class instead :)** (handles even lists , nested lists and json)

```
public class Utility {

    public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(Object json) throws JSONException {

        if(json instanceof JSONObject)
            return _jsonToMap_((JSONObject)json) ;

        else if (json instanceof String)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject((String)json) ;
            return _jsonToMap_(jsonObject) ;
        }
        return null ;
    }


   private static Map<String, Object> _jsonToMap_(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        if(json != JSONObject.NULL) {
            retMap = toMap(json);
        }
        return retMap;
    }


    private static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
        while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            Object value = object.get(key);

            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            map.put(key, value);
        }
        return map;
    }


    public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            Object value = array.get(i);
            if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
                value = toList((JSONArray) value);
            }

            else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
                value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
            }
            list.add(value);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

To convert your **JSON string to hashmap** use this :

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>(Utility.jsonToMap(response)) ;
```

Comment: This is much better than than accepted answer as it handles nested and complex objects. Helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
String string = "{\"phonetype\":\"N95\",\"cat\":\"WP\"}";

try {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(string);

    hashMap.put("phonetype", json.getString("phonetype"));
    hashMap.put("cat", json.getString("cat"));
} catch (JSONException e) {
     // TODO Handle expection!
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use empty catch blocks.

Comment: This solutions is suitable only for `{"phonetype":"N95","cat":"WP"}`, it should be generic.

Comment: Catch blocks are not the focus here, so I agree - keep them empty  to focus on the actual logic

Answer (score 2):

In Java we can do it using the following statement . We need to use Jackson ObjectMapper for the same and provide the HashMap.class as the mapping class. Finally store the result as a HashMap object.

```
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, HashMap.class);
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this yourself, I suggest.
Use a library, e.g. the Gson library from Google.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0):

consider this json string

```
{
    "12": [
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/12/12_960x540_200k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "200k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 960,
            "video_height": 540,
            "file_size": 125465600
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/12/12_960x540_80k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "80k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 960,
            "video_height": 540,
            "file_size": 50186240
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/12/12_640x360_201k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "201k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 145934731
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/12/12_640x360_199k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "199k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 145800030
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/12/12_640x360_79k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "79k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 71709477
        }
    ],
    "13": [
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/13/13_960x540_200k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "200k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 960,
            "video_height": 540,
            "file_size": 172902400
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/13/13_960x540_80k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "80k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 960,
            "video_height": 540,
            "file_size": 69160960
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/13/13_640x360_201k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "201k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 199932081
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/13/13_640x360_199k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "199k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 199630781
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/13/13_640x360_79k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "79k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 98303415
        }
    ],
    "14": [
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/14/14_960x540_200k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "200k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 960,
            "video_height": 540,
            "file_size": 205747200
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/14/14_960x540_80k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "80k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 960,
            "video_height": 540,
            "file_size": 82298880
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/14/14_640x360_201k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "201k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 237769546
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/14/14_640x360_199k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "199k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 237395552
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/14/14_640x360_79k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "79k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 116885686
        }
    ],
    "15": [
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/15/15_960x540_200k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "200k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 960,
            "video_height": 540,
            "file_size": 176128000
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/15/15_960x540_80k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "80k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 960,
            "video_height": 540,
            "file_size": 70451200
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/15/15_640x360_201k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "201k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 204263286
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/15/15_640x360_199k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "199k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 204144447
        },
        {
            "dash_url": "http://mediaserver.superprofs.com:1935/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/superprofs-media/private/lectures/15/15_640x360_79k.mp4/manifest.mpd",
            "video_bitrate": "79k",
            "audio_bitrate": "32k",
            "video_width": 640,
            "video_height": 360,
            "file_size": 100454382
        }
    ]
}
```

using jackson parser

```
 private static ObjectMapper underScoreToCamelCaseMapper;

    static {
        final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        underScoreToCamelCaseMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        underScoreToCamelCaseMapper.setDateFormat(df);
        underScoreToCamelCaseMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        underScoreToCamelCaseMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        underScoreToCamelCaseMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
                PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
}
    public static <T> T parseUnderScoredResponse(String json, Class<T> classOfT) {
        try {
            if (json == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return underScoreToCamelCaseMapper.readValue(json, classOfT);

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```

use following code to parse

```
 HashMap<String, ArrayList<Video>> integerArrayListHashMap =
                JsonHandler.parseUnderScoredResponse(test, MyHashMap.class);
```

where MyHashMap is

```
 private static class MyHashMap extends HashMap<String,ArrayList<Video>>{
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No JSON libraries, just String and HashMap. 
 Keeps it simple! 
Hope it suits to all.

 // JSON Transform to HashMap example based on String

```
    String tempJson = "{\"incomePhone\":\"213121122\",\"clientId\":\"1001\",\"clientAccountManager\":\"Gestor de Conta 1\",\"clientRetailBranch\":\"100\",\"phoneAccountManager\":\"7800100\"}";
    System.out.println(tempJson);

    String[] parts = tempJson.split(",");
    HashMap<String,String> jsonHash = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for(int i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
        parts[i]    =   parts[i].replace("\"", "");
        parts[i]    =   parts[i].replace("{", "");
        parts[i]    =   parts[i].replace("}", "");
        String[] subparts = parts[i].split(":");
        jsonHash.put(subparts[0],subparts[1]);
    }
```

Comment: This is going to fail with any arrays and probably nested objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map<String, String> parseJSON(JSONObject json, Map<String, String> dataFields) throws JSONException {
        Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            String val = null;
            try {
                JSONObject value = json.getJSONObject(key);
                parseJSON(value, dataFields);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (json.isNull(key)) {
                    val = "";
                } else {
                    try {
                        val = json.getString(key);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            if (val != null) {
                dataFields.put(key, val);
            }
        }
        return dataFields;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to parse Json to HashMap

```
public static HashMap<String, String> jsonToMap(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            try {
                Iterator<String> iterator = json.keys();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = iterator.next();
                    String value = json.getString(key);
                    map.put(key, value);
                }

                return map;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("phonetype","N95");
jsonObj.put("cat","WP");
```

jsonObj to  Hashmap as following using gson

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObj.toString(), HashMap.class);
```

package used

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of an easy and simple way to create a Hashmap from a JSON string by only using the JSON simple library:

> {"Collection":{"Item_Type":"Any","Name":"A","Item_ID":"000014"},"Object_Name":"System"}

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator; 
import java.util.Map;  
import org.json.simple.JSONObject; 
import org.json.simple.parser.*;

public class JSONRead {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
    Object obj = new JSONParser().parse(new FileReader("D:\\other.json"));
    
    HashMap<String,String> map =new HashMap<String,String>();
    
    // typecasting obj to JSONObject 
    JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
    
    Map Item_Id = ((Map)jo.get("Collection"));
            
    Iterator<Map.Entry> itr1 = Item_Id.entrySet().iterator(); 
    while (itr1.hasNext()) { 
        Map.Entry pair = itr1.next(); 
        String key = (String) pair.getKey();
        String value = (String) pair.getValue();
        System.out.println( pair.getKey() + " : " + pair.getValue()); 
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    
    System.out.println(map)
    System.out.println(map.get("Item"));        
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use Jackson to do this. I have yet to find a simple Gson solution.

Where `data_map.json` is a JSON (object) resource file
and `data_list.json` is a JSON (array) resource file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * Based on:
 * 
 * http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/
 */
public class JsonLoader {
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJ_MAPPER;
    private static final TypeReference<Map<String,Object>> OBJ_MAP;
    private static final TypeReference<List<Map<String,Object>>> OBJ_LIST;

    static {
        OBJ_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();
        OBJ_MAP = new TypeReference<Map<String,Object>>(){};
        OBJ_LIST = new TypeReference<List<Map<String,Object>>>(){};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(jsonToString(parseJsonString(read("data_map.json", true))));
            System.out.println(jsonToString(parseJsonString(read("data_array.json", true))));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final Object parseJsonString(String jsonString) {
        try {
            if (jsonString.startsWith("{")) {
                return readJsonObject(jsonString);
            } else if (jsonString.startsWith("[")) {
                return readJsonArray(jsonString);
            }
        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static String jsonToString(Object json) throws JsonProcessingException {
        return OBJ_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
    }

    private static final Map<String,Object> readJsonObject(String jsonObjectString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        return OBJ_MAPPER.readValue(jsonObjectString, OBJ_MAP);
    }

    private static final List<Map<String,Object>> readJsonArray(String jsonArrayString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        return OBJ_MAPPER.readValue(jsonArrayString, OBJ_LIST);
    }

    public static final Map<String,Object> loadJsonObject(String path, boolean isResource) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        return OBJ_MAPPER.readValue(load(path, isResource), OBJ_MAP);
    }

    public static final List<Map<String,Object>> loadJsonArray(String path, boolean isResource) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
        return OBJ_MAPPER.readValue(load(path, isResource), OBJ_LIST);
    }

    private static final URL pathToUrl(String path, boolean isResource) throws MalformedURLException {
        if (isResource) {
            return JsonLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
        }

        return new URL("file:/" + path);
    }

    protected static File load(String path, boolean isResource) throws MalformedURLException {
        return load(pathToUrl(path, isResource));
    }

    protected static File load(URL url) {
        try {
            return new File(url.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return new File(url.getPath());
        }
    }

    public static String read(String path, boolean isResource) throws IOException {
        return read(path, "UTF-8", isResource);
    }

    public static String read(String path, String charset, boolean isResource) throws IOException {
        return read(pathToUrl(path, isResource), charset);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static String read(URL url, String charset) throws IOException {
        return new Scanner(url.openStream(), charset).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }
}
```

---

## Extra

Here is the complete code for [Dheeraj Sachan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3314058/dheeraj-sachan)'s example.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.PropertyAccessor;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;

public class JsonHandler {
    private static ObjectMapper propertyMapper;

    static {
        final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        propertyMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        propertyMapper.setDateFormat(df);
        propertyMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        propertyMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        propertyMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    }

    private static class MyHashMap extends HashMap<String, List<Video>>{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7023107716981734468L;
    }

    private static class Video implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -446275421030765463L;

        private String dashUrl;
        private String videoBitrate;
        private String audioBitrate;
        private int videoWidth;
        private int videoHeight;
        private long fileSize;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Video [url=" + dashUrl + ", video=" + videoBitrate + ", audio=" + audioBitrate
                    + ", width=" + videoWidth + ", height=" + videoHeight + ", size=" + fileSize + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, List<Video>> map = loadJson("sample.json", true);
            Iterator<Entry<String, List<Video>>> lectures = map.entrySet().iterator();

            while (lectures.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, List<Video>> lecture = lectures.next();

                System.out.printf("Lecture #%s%n", lecture.getKey());

                for (Video video : lecture.getValue()) {
                    System.out.println(video);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> T parseUnderScoredResponse(String json, Class<T> classOfT) {
        try {
            if (json == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return propertyMapper.readValue(json, classOfT);

        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static URL pathToUrl(String path, boolean isResource) throws MalformedURLException {
        if (isResource) {
            return JsonHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
        }

        return new URL("file:/" + path);
    }

    public static File load(String path, boolean isResource) throws MalformedURLException {
        return load(pathToUrl(path, isResource));
    }

    public static File load(URL url) {
        try {
            return new File(url.toURI());
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            return new File(url.getPath());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static String readFile(URL url, String charset) throws IOException {
        return new Scanner(url.openStream(), charset).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }

    public static String loadJsonString(String path, boolean isResource) throws IOException {
        return readFile(path, isResource, "UTF-8");
    }

    public static String readFile(String path, boolean isResource, String charset) throws IOException {
        return readFile(pathToUrl(path, isResource), charset);
    }

    public static HashMap<String, List<Video>> loadJson(String jsonString) throws IOException {
        return JsonHandler.parseUnderScoredResponse(jsonString, MyHashMap.class);
    }

    public static HashMap<String, List<Video>> loadJson(String path, boolean isResource) throws IOException {
        return loadJson(loadJsonString(path, isResource));
    }
}
```