# Getting a JSON array from an URL and converting it into a HashMap in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, hashmap

I have a URL, lets say for example `www.example.com/movies/`, which has the following JSON array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "alice",
        "director": "Tim Burton",
        "year": "2010",
        "image":"alice",
        "length": "108 min",
        "stars": "Mia Wasikowska, Johnny Depp, Helena Bonham Carter",
        "name": "Alice in Wonderland",
        "description": "Nineteen-year-old Alice returns to the magical world from her childhood adventure, where she reunites with her old friends and learns of her true destiny: to end the Red Queen's reign of terror.",
        "rating": "6.5",
        "url": "http:\/\/ia.media-imdb.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTMwNjAxMTc0Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc3ODk5Mg@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_"
    },
    {
        "id": "avator",
        "director": "Cameron",
        "year": "2009",
        "image":"avatar",
        "length": "162 min",
        "stars": "Sam Worthington, Zoe Saldana, Sigourney Weaver",
        "name": "Avatar",
        "description": "A paraplegic Marine dispatched to the moon Pandora on a unique mission becomes torn between following his orders and protecting the world he feels is his home.",
        "rating": "7.9",
        "url": "http:\/\/ia.media-imdb.com\/images\/M\/MV5BMTYwOTEwNjAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwODc5MTUwMw@@._V1_SY317_CR0,0,214,317_AL_"
    }]
```

I want to fetch this JSON array from Android and convert it into a Hashmap. Please help me.

Comment: Take a look [How to ask question in SO?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap

Comment: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011200/creating-hashmap-from-a-json-string

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get JSON Response from URL

```
    HttpClient client;
    String _responseMain = "";
    HttpResponse responseMain;


        AsyncTask<String, String, String> _Task = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {


            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) 
            {

                if (NetworkAvailablity.checkNetworkStatus(CurrentActivity.this)) 
                {




                    try {
                        // Creating HTTP client
                        client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                        // Creating HTTP Post
                        HttpGet httpGet= new HttpGet("http://api.myjson.com/bins/44tys%22");




                        responseMain = client.execute(httpGet);
                        HttpEntity entitity = responseMain.getEntity();

                        _responseMain = EntityUtils.toString(entitity); // content will be consume only once
                System.out.println("Response : "+_responseMain);


                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // writing error to Log
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        e.printStackTrace();


                    }


                } 
                else
                {

                }

                return null;

            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
            {
                if (_responseMain!=null&&!_responseMain.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
 try {
                            JSONArray _jArr = new JSONArray("YOUR_JSON_STRING");
                            HashMap<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            if (_jArr.length()>0) {

                                for (int i = 0; i < _jArr.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject _jObject = _jArr.getJSONObject(i);
                                    String _id = _jObject.getString("id");
                                    pairs.put("id", _id);

                                    String _director = _jObject.getString("director");
                                    pairs.put("director", _director);

                                    String _year = _jObject.getString("year");
                                    pairs.put("year", _year);

                                    String _image = _jObject.getString("image");
                                    pairs.put("image", _image);

                                    String _length = _jObject.getString("length");
                                    pairs.put("length", _length);

                                    String _stars = _jObject.getString("stars");
                                    pairs.put("stars", _stars);

                                    String _name = _jObject.getString("name");
                                    pairs.put("name", _name);

                                    String _description = _jObject.getString("description");
                                    pairs.put("description", _description);

                                    String _rating= _jObject.getString("rating");
                                    pairs.put("rating", _rating);

                                    String _url = _jObject.getString("url");
                                    pairs.put("url", _url);

                                }
                            }

                            }



                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }                   
}
                } else {

                }

            }
        };
        _Task.execute((String[]) null);
```

Comment: the leading underscore only makes the readability worse, imho

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, Shoeb. But I have not saved the json file in my project. I have to fetch it from an URL. And I have to populate the values in a List.

Comment: You can populate values in list, so you can use that String values which i have made.

Comment: I have the code to convert the json array to a hashmap. I need a code to read the json code from this url  "http://api.myjson.com/bins/44tys". This URL has my json code.