# How to get array number JSON android

Tags: android, json

I have JSON :

```
{"elements":[{"id":5,"name":"Mathematics","shortName":"math","links":{"courses":[15,30,46,47]}}]}
```

My code :

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            //Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                products = json.getJSONArray("elements");

                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    int ids = c.getInt(TAG_PID);
                    String id = String.valueOf(ids);

                    if (id.compareTo(id_kh) == 0) {
                        object = c.getJSONObject("links");
                        JSONArray courses = object.getJSONArray("courses");///???????????
                        //result = courses.split("[,]");
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"abc",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I dont know to get array number after "courses".

Comment: Can you post the code you have... (in format) please

Comment: "elements" i can get by getJSONArray, "id" i can get by getInt, "name" i can get by getString, "links" i can get by getJSONObject. so "courses" i can get by what?

Comment: Edit your question and add  your parsing code.

Comment: İf i were you, I would prefer Gson.

https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

`courses` is a `JSONArray`, so you can do like that:

```
JSONArray coursesArray = linksObject.getJSONArray("courses");
```

**UPDATE:**

To get values from `coursesArray` :

```
int value = coursesArray.optInt(position);
```

Comment: how can i use with coursesArray? I want have array int[]. help me!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use HashMaps. Here you have an example ([creating Hashmap from a JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011200/creating-hashmap-from-a-json-string)
) how to get it from a JSON String.

Particularly for the "courses", once you have been parsed until there, I would use a `HashMap<String,List<Integer>>`

Answer (score 0):

Almost there. Once you get your

```
JSONArray courses = object.getJSONArray("courses");
```

simply iterate over its values:

```
// you wanted these numbers in an array
// so let's create one, with size being number of elements in 
// JSONArray courses
int[] courseIds = new int[courses.length()];

for (int j=0; j<courses.length(); j++) {
    // assign current number to the appropriate element in your array of ints
    coursesId[j] = courses.getInt(j);
    Log.d("TAG", "number: " + number);
}
```

The above will save these numbers in an array and print them too:

> number: 15
>
> number: 30
>
> number: 46
>
> number: 47

Just keep in mind that "courses" key might not exist, the array might be empty etc.