# Listview item based on JSON id value

Tags: android, json, listview, hashmap

I'm Creating the `ListView` which get the response from JSON.The JSON response contain the object like id and title.

```
   {
  "meal": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "title": "MEAL 1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "title": "MEAL 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "title": "MEAL 3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "title": "MEAL 4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using `HashMap` i gave this title to the `ListView`. `OnItemClickListener` i would like to get the JSON id instead of position in `ListView`.How to do it?

This JSON id is part of url for my new activity.

Comment: This question is already answered many times....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON Array (Not Json Object) in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977144/how-to-parse-json-array-not-json-object-in-android)

Comment: @karan.. My question is to pass the id value to get new activity. This JSON id is url for my new activity.

Comment: @Karan If you say it has dublicate put answer to this question, i will make accepted answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011200/creating-hashmap-from-a-json-string

Comment: I also say that please don't parse by your self. Use GSON which is google's auto parse. And try to use Model structure.

Comment: I converted it to HashMap. now my question is how to get the particular id from the HashMap :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {     
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String value = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
           //display value here 
     Log.i("TAG","Position : " + position);

     }
});
```

may helps you.

Comment: It shows like {titleName=MEAL 1, idName=1}. Because HasMap contains both id and title.:(

Comment: take position and do your stuff with listview position

Comment: from json you can get both id and name separately. then pass to listview. after that you will get separately both items from hash map

Comment: lv1.get(position).get("idName")  is used to separate the idName. :)