# How do I convert java.lang.String to java.util.LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, json, spring

I converted `java.lang.String` to `or.simple.json.JSONObject`. Now I'm unable to cast it to HashMap.

```
org.json.JSONObject jso = new org.json.JSONObject("{"phonetype":"N95","cat":"WP"}");        
LinkedHashMap h = (LinkedHashMap) jso.get("phonetype");
System.out.println(h);
```

and I'm getting an error:

> "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.LinkedHashMap"

Comment: Please look into this stackoverflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011200/creating-hashmap-from-a-json-string

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011200/creating-hashmap-from-a-json-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating Hashmap from a JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011200/creating-hashmap-from-a-json-string)

Answer (score 1):

1. JSONObject has following constructor

   public JSONObject(Map map) {
       super(map);
   }

This means you cannot create JSONObject, passing String in consctructor. But you can using map

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("phonetype","N95");
    map.put("cat", "WP");
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(map);
```

2. get method has signature

   public V get(Object key)

This means that if you want to get map, value should be Map generic. For example

```
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    map.put("phonetype","N95");
    map.put("cat", "WP");

    Map<String, Map> toConstructor = new LinkedHashMap() {{
        put("map", map);
    }};
    JSONObject jso = new JSONObject(toConstructor);
    LinkedHashMap h = (LinkedHashMap) jso.get("map");
    System.out.println(h);
```

In your case you try to cast String to LinkedHashMap, so ClassCastException was thrown