# Convert json String containing array to Map in Java

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I need to convert String to Map for the following json string in Java:
Please note that this json string has array in it and that is where I am facing the issue:

```
{
   "type":"auth",
   "amount":"16846",
   "level3":{
      "amount":"0.00",
      "zip":"37209",
      "items":[
         {
            "description":"temp1",
            "commodity_code":"1",
            "product_code":"11"
         },
         {
            "description":"temp2",
            "commodity_code":"2",
            "product_code":"22"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I tried couple of ways as mentioned in below links:

[Convert JSON string to Map – Jackson](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/)

[Parse the JSONObject and create HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22011887/948268)

Error I am getting:

> JSON parser error: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String
>   out of START_OBJECT token ... }; line: 3, column: 20] (through
>   reference chain:
>   java.util.LinkedHashMap["level3"])com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT
>   token

So to give more details about what I am doing with the Map is, this map will be converted back to the json string using following method:

```
    public static String getJSON(Object map) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(byteStream);
    JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = objectMapper.getFactory().createGenerator(stream, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
    objectMapper.writeValue(jsonGenerator, map);
    stream.flush();
    jsonGenerator.close();
    return new String(byteStream.toByteArray());
}
```

Comment: Facing what issue?  What have you tried?  How did it not work?  If you [edit] your question to include your attempt(s), it'd be a lot easier to figure out where you're getting stuck.

Comment: Added details, essentially I want to know that does the way I am trying to do it will also take care of Array within the json string?

Comment: map appropriates for key-value pairs from json, but you have complex data structure. Which elements do you have to extract from json?

Comment: It would also be useful to know what you expected the map to look like. For example, what should happen with the 'level3' object.

Comment: Added details about what I need to do with the HashMap.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a Map for this. Create a proper class structure and use a library like Jackson to deserialize your JSON.

Comment: It is actually the existing code in the project but now I have scenario where we could also get array within it. So, cannot change it, I need to have the Map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot parse your JSON content into a `Map<String, String>`
(like it is done in the two links you posted).
But you can parse it into a `Map<String, Object>`.

For example  like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File file = new File("example.json");
Map<String, Object> map;
map = mapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```