# Simple JSON parsing with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I did not write a lot in Java yet, but I wonder if there is a simple way, to parse JSON and work with the results into a map just like we would do it in other modern languages:

```
string = loadFromSomeWhere(URI)
dictionary = JSON.parse(string)
// do something with the dictionary
```

I do not want to define a POJO first, nor will I deal with the deepness of the JSON structure. And I can assume, that the file will stay small enought, so event driven parsing is not necessary.

I need to use Jackson and found only way to complicated approaches.

Comment: Where you're receiving your JSON? in Spring controller? or you have it as a literal String value?

Comment: Why do you need to use Jackson? Java has had JSON parsing built in for _quite_ a while now - https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/json.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating Hashmap from a JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011200/creating-hashmap-from-a-json-string)

Comment: There's a lot of material on this stuff online! Google is your friend: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525042/how-to-convert-a-json-string-to-a-mapstring-string-with-jackson-json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map http://websystique.com/java/json/jackson-convert-java-map-to-from-json/ https://howtodoinjava.com/jackson/jackson-json-to-from-hashmap/

Comment: Moreover, if you want a typed Map (exploiting java generics), you can do : `Map<String, MyPojo> typedMap = mapper.readValue(jsonStream, new TypeReference<Map<String, MyPojo>>() {}); ` -> from this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map

Comment: As far as the docs go, it is that JSON-P what you mean. But I still have to include a dependecy, don't I? @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Comment: It's the built in JSON parser, searching for any of the classes used in that article will tell you exactly which (built-in) package to import for your code to work. Or, if you're in Eclipse or another intelligent IDE, you should be able to just write the code and it'll go "hey you need to import xyz for this to work. Do  that now?" and then you accept that suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

You can use external Json libraries for java - such as com.google.gson - this would almost allow similar operation as JSON we use for javascript.
you can initialize it as 
Gson gson = new Gson();

```
YouJaravObject obj = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, YouJaravObject.class);
```

You can also have a map or a list - which your json string can be converted to.

if you use mvn build you need to also include gson into dependency list of build as below

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can also use "jackson.databind" for more generic conversion

```
JsonNode jsonBody
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
om.treeToValue(jsonBody.get("metaData"), abc.class);
```

which ll let you access your node / tree from json

Comment: Please read my post, I need to use Jackson