# Can I dynamically create a Java object in the run time via JSON?

Tags: java, json, object

For example, I have a JSON format like this:

> {"class":"MySpecialClass", "attri1":"value1", "attri2":"value2"}

I would like to create a Object, which is a `MySpecialClass` Object, and get two attribute, `attri1` and `attri2` with the value of `value1` and `value2`.

Here is the requirement:

1. I have a class file, named, `MySpecialClass`, and have `attri1`, and `attri2`, can I create this object, and assign the value in this?
2. I `DONT'T` have the class file `MySpecialClass`, I would like to generate it on the runtime, is this possible to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first case is perfectly feasible using any Java/JSON parser.

Your second case is possible, but hard work.

You can construct classes at runtime using *bytecode engineering* - e.g. using [Apache BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/manual.html). Note that the JSON will contail fields only, and not behaviour nor type.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/google/gson it does what you want

Answer (score 0):

You want a JSON processor, like [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes). I'm not sure you can easily do your second case this way, for that you may be best looking at a JVM JavaScript implementation unless you want to get into stuff like on the fly bytecode manipulation. There's [one in the Java6 runtime](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/).