# Java String to JSON and then JSON to array

Tags: java, arrays, json, string, arraylist

I have the following String code and I want to convert to json and iterate through items and put them into an arraylist in Java.
I also have a class called Users whith its attributes and getters/setters(id, nick, age, online, avatar)how should i do:

code:

```
//this is the real code
String a = "{"id":"1","nick":"jhon","age":20,"online":1,"avatar":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/image.jpeg"},{"id":"2","nick":"mike","age":45,"online":0,"avatar":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/image.jpeg"},{"id":"3","nick":"carl","age":12,"online":1,"avatar":"http:\/\/www.example.com/image.jpeg"},{"id":"4","nick":"ana","age":22,"online":0,"avatar":"http:\/\/www.example.com\/image.jpeg"}";


//this is what i want to do
String a = real code sample;
Json b = a.toJson; // something like this
Arraylist<User> list = new Arraylist<User>();
for each b{
     list.add(     new user(b.getId(),b.getNick()....));
}
```

i want to do something like that and of course the code is an example and here it's not well written.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you need to escape the quotes `"` by `\"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Comment: Check out http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.String)

Comment: Google's Gson seems like a good choice for you: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library which has good documentation for how to use. You can easly parse objects to JSON and JSON to object. So it may be a better alternative for your own parser.

It also supports Arrays and Collections.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to validate you array first on [JSONLINT](http://jsonlint.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations) is quite nice for this sort of thing - I've been using it for some time with no problems. I've heard nice things about Gson as well, but had no reason to switch from Jackson.  [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/json-tutorial.html) also can work with Json.

Instead of working with a special "JSON" object, Jackson (and I believe Gson as well) stuff the JSON values into a POJO.  You use the annotations to customize how the values are read and written.

FWIW, JSON processing is easy with a library like this, but also something you don't want to do much - it's relatively expensive in terms of CPU.  It's not that the libs are slow - that kind of text processing is a lot of work.