# Parse HttpServletRequest contains jsonp string

Tags: java, parsing, servlets, jetty, jsonp

When I try to send cross-domain jsonp request with:

```
$.getJSON(url + "?callback=?",
    value : 'John',
    record : {
        value : 'a',
        list : [ 1, 2 ]
    });
```

Then i try to get it with java servlet like this:

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                         HttpServletResponse response)
               throws ServletException, IOException {

        String output = request.getParameter("callback") 
                            + "({\"response\":\"test\"});";

        response.setContentType("application/javascript;charset=utf-8");

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(output);
    }
}
```

Inside servlet request string has parameter names:

```
_=1353482336546
value=John
record[value]=a
```

**How can i parse request string to original JSON?**

Im using embedded jetty server and I want to use "JSON to Object" jetty parser on JSON string

Comment: do u want to parse json to object..try google gson http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: But can i make it without gson dependency? Is there a way to convert query string to original JSON?

Comment: query string to original JSON means..what i know.. "request from browser are converted to java object on server and response java object on server is converted to json string and send the browser"..writing just for reference..

Comment: I think this links will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245840/how-to-convert-string-to-jsonobject-in-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can apply flexjson to parse json string to an object. Please take a look at:

[live example](https://gist.github.com/yutax77/2988072#file-figures-java)

[flexjson library](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/)