# Simple JSON Java storage methods

Tags: java, json

I have a simple JSON string in my class.

```
String json = "{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}";
```

And I want create 3 simple methods that will

```
1. Put value in my JSON string.
2. Get value in my JSON string.
3. Remove value in my JSON string.
```

Is there any simple library in Java? Or I have to implement it myself?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a JSON string to object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java)

Comment: Hi you can use, json-lib-2.1-jdk1.5.jar or Json.jar for using the JSON methods with Java

Comment: Did you even google "java json library"?

Comment: Is there any method without converting to Map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) can convert Java objects and JSON to each other.

Comment: Yes Gson works well. There's also http://jackson.codehaus.org/ if Gson doesn't float your boat.

Comment: If using GSON. I need to use MAP?     String json = "{'data1':100,'data2':'hello'}";
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map obj = gson.fromJson(json, Map.class);

Comment: If the object that your are serializing/deserializing is a ParameterizedType (i.e. contains at least one type parameter and may be an array) then you must use the toJson(Object, Type) or fromJson(String, Type) method. See http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(java.lang.String, java.lang.reflect.Type)

Comment: Note that your example json string (above comment) does not correspond to a valid Java `Map` (with values of boxed primitive types) because the types of the values differ. If the types vary, you should read the json into a custom object rather than a `Map`.

Answer (score 3):

Use Jackson:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Serialization:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValue(new Simple());
```

and with POJO like:

```
public class Simple {
    public int x = 1;
    public int y = 2;
}
```

you would get something like:

```
{"x":1, "y":2}
```

(except that by default output is not indented: you can enabled indentation using standard Jackson mechanisms)

Deserializing POJOs from JSON:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Simple value = mapper
   .readValue("{\"x\": 1, \"y\": 2}", Simple.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a pretty extensive evaluation of json-java libraries a few months ago, and chose json-smart: http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/

Has been working well.