# Read out elements of a string in specific order

Tags: java, string, element

For some reasons I have to use a specific string in my project. This is the text file (it's a JSON File):

```
{"algorithm": 
[
    { "key": "onGapLeft", "value" : "moveLeft" },
    { "key": "onGapFront", "value" : "moveForward" },
    { "key": "onGapRight", "value" : "moveRight" },
    { "key": "default", "value" : "moveBackward" }
]
}
```

I've defined it in JAVA like this:

```
static String input = "{\"algorithm\": \n"+
"[ \n" +
    "{ \"key\": \"onGapLeft\", \"value\" : \"moveLeft\" }, \n" +
    "{ \"key\": \"onGapFront\", \"value\" : \"moveForward\" }, \n" +
    "{ \"key\": \"onGapRight\", \"value\" : \"moveRight\" }, \n" +
    "{ \"key\": \"default\", \"value\" : \"moveBackward\" } \n" +
"] \n" +
"}";
```

Now I have to isolate the keys and values in an array:

```
key[0] = onGapLeft; value[0] = moveLeft;
key[1] = onGapFront; value[1] = moveForward;
key[2] = onGapRight; value[2] = moveRight;
key[3] = default; value[3] = moveBackward;
```

I'm new to JAVA and don't understand the string class very well. Is there an easy way to get to that result? You would help me really!

Thanks!

UPDATE:
I didn't explained it well enough, sorry. This program will run on a LEGO NXT Robot. JSON won't work there as I want it to so I have to interpret this JSON File as a normal STRING! Hope that explains what I want :)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If your input String is a JSON String then you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Comment: Hey, thanks!
JSON is unfortunatily no option because it's not running on my Lego NXT Robot. SO I have to interpret this JSON File as a string.

I'm sorry I didn't explain that well enough! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose a solution in several step.

**1)** Let's get the different parts of your ~JSON String. We will use a pattern to get the different `{.*}` parts :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{.*\\}");
  Matcher matcher = p.matcher(input);
  while (matcher.find()) {
    lines.add(matcher.group());
  }
}
```

(you should take a look at [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html))

Now, `lines` contains 4 String :

```
{ "key": "onGapLeft", "value" : "moveLeft" }
{ "key": "onGapFront", "value" : "moveForward" }
{ "key": "onGapRight", "value" : "moveRight" }
{ "key": "default", "value" : "moveBackward" }
```

Given a String like one of those, you can remove curly brackets with a call to `String#replaceAll();`

```
List<String> cleanLines = new ArrayList<String>();
for(String line : lines) {
  //replace curly brackets with... nothing.
  //added a call to trim() in order to remove whitespace characters.
  cleanLines.add(line.replaceAll("[{}]","").trim());
}
```

(You should take a look at [String String#replaceAll(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29))

Now, `cleanLines` contains :

```
"key": "onGapLeft", "value" : "moveLeft"
"key": "onGapFront", "value" : "moveForward"
"key": "onGapRight", "value" : "moveRight"
"key": "default", "value" : "moveBackward"
```

**2)** Let's parse one of those lines :

Given a line like :

```
"key": "onGapLeft", "value" : "moveLeft"
```

You can split it on `,` character using String#split(). It will give you a String[] containing 2 elements :

```
//parts[0] = "key": "onGapLeft"
//parts[1] = "value" : "moveLeft"
String[] parts = line.split(",");
```

(You should take a look at [String[] String#split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29))

Let's clean those parts (remove "") and assign them to some variables:

```
String keyStr = parts[0].replaceAll("\"","").trim(); //Now, key = key: onGapLeft
String valueStr = parts[1].replaceAll("\"","").trim();//Now, value = value : moveLeft

//Then, you split `key: onGapLeft` with character `:`
String key = keyStr.split(":")[1].trim();

//And the same for `value : moveLeft` : 
String value = valueStr.split(":")[1].trim();
```

That's it !

You should also take a look at [Oracle's tutorial on regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) (This one is really important and you should invest time on it).

Comment: Thank you so much! This was my last attempt to get this program to work properly and you rescued me! :)

(sadly I can't upvote this solution because I need 15 rep)

Comment: Just one more question! :)

String[] parts = line.split(",");

line is in your case a local String inside the for argument. Should that be cleanLines.Split(",")?

Comment: No :) cleanLines is a `String[]`. `String#split()` is only applicable to a `String`. You need to iterate on the `String[]` to work with lines one by one.

Comment: Oh my god.. I'm going crazy now.
I don't want to bother you any longer but the robot does "not support  regular expressions". I didn't know that, I learned it the hard way right now.. Is there any easy solution to modify your solution so it didn't use regular expressions?

Comment: Then you have 2 solutions : 1) You parse manually : use String.toCharArray() to convert your String to a char[] and interate on it. You should also be able to reimplement the split method without regex. 2) Some people developped some minimal JSON parser that you can include or copy-paste in your project : see http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/04/18/minimal-json-parser-for-java/

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented the split method now with NXT conform string operations. It's working now! You've been a great help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a JSON parser library here. For example, with [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) you could parse it as

```
String input = "{\"algorithm\": \n"+
        "[ \n" +
            "{ \"key\": \"onGapLeft\", \"value\" : \"moveLeft\" }, \n" +
            "{ \"key\": \"onGapFront\", \"value\" : \"moveForward\" }, \n" +
            "{ \"key\": \"onGapRight\", \"value\" : \"moveRight\" }, \n" +
            "{ \"key\": \"default\", \"value\" : \"moveBackward\" } \n" +
        "] \n" +
        "}";

JSONObject root = new JSONObject(input);
JSONArray map = root.getJSONArray("algorithm");

for (int i = 0; i < map.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject entry = map.getJSONObject(i);
    System.out.println(entry.getString("key") + ": "
                          + entry.getString("value"));
}
```

***Output** :*

```
onGapLeft: moveLeft
onGapFront: moveForward
onGapRight: moveRight
default: moveBackward
```

Comment: Hey, thanks!
JSON is unfortunatily no option because it's not running on my Lego NXT Robot. SO I have to interpret this JSON File as a string.

I'm sorry I didn't explain that well enough! :)