# Comnverting Json into Java object

Tags: java, json

I  must receive the following JSON from request

```
{
  "class":"classname"
  "method":"methodName",
  "args": {
    "arg1Name":"arg1Value",
    "arg2Name":"arg2Value"
    "arg3Name":"arg3Value"
    "arg4Name":"arg4Value"
  }
}
```

I need to parse this json and create an instance of specified class and call specified method with args. What solution can you suggest?

Comment: Try using GSON, it works well.

Comment: Take a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java