# Angularjs: passing an object to java API

Tags: angularjs, object, serialization

My object is `info`

`info
Date: ""
ids: Array[1]
__proto__: Object`
It has all the values and I send it in angular.
On the java side if the input parameter is like

```
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> update(@RequestBody myObject input) {...}
```

I get an error: 400 (Bad Request) 
`HTTP Status 400 -
type Status report
message
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

But if in the api I do

```
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> update(@RequestBody String input) {...}
```

It works fine! what is wrong with it? myObject does have only

```
String Date;
String[] ids;
```

Comment: As Ian mentioned you have to deserialize the JSON string into an Object. Here's a post that covers a few options for doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're sending data from AngularJS using $http.post or $http.put? Angular sends JSON as a string in the request body. I would suggest you decode the JSON into a Java object using a library like [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) (see deserialization).

Comment: Thanks Is there a way to send an object from angular? I remembered I did it before using .map something like this

Comment: Not in the way you are probably thinking. Angular sends data to the server via HTTP. The request body is composed of text.