# Parsing JSON array to java object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to parse using `Jackson` mapper to parse big JSON to java object. I have very big JSON but came across this little piece in it and not sure how to parse.
Here is the JSON, the format of it looks little different. I am trying to understand how can I parse it to an object.

```
{
    "coordinates": [
        [
            [
                -72.943068,
                45.842298
            ],
            [
                -72.943075,
                45.841859
            ]
        ]
    ]
}
```

I don't understand which format it is in, and how I can parse it to object.

Comment: That would be an object containing a `double[][][]`.

Comment: [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Comment: I wanted to know how the object look like?

Comment: This looks like a GeoJSON coordinate. What do you want to do? Map it with a POJO? Walking the JSON directly? Jackson can do both

Comment: I wanted to map it to a POJO but not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how really big is your `JSON`. If you can load it to memory, you can use the simplest way:
**Solution 1:**
POJO class:

```
class CoordinatesContainer {

    private double[][][] coordinates;

    public double[][][] getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(double[][][] coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(1024);
        for (double[] arrayItem : coordinates[0]) {
            builder.append(Arrays.toString(arrayItem));
            builder.append(", ");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CoordinatesContainer coordinatesContainer = mapper.readValue(json, CoordinatesContainer.class);
System.out.println(coordinatesContainer);
```

Above program prints:

```
[-72.943068, 45.842298], [-72.943075, 45.841859]
```

**Solution 2:**
But if your `JSON` is really big and you are not able to load it to memory, you should consider [Jackson Streaming API](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/01/entry_132.html). In this case you should not create POJO class and try to process each element "node" by "node":

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;

public class JsonProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File json = new File("/x/data.json");
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser parser = jsonFactory.createParser(json);
        // Skip all elements to first array
        while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        }
        parser.nextToken();
        // First level
        while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            // Skip inner start array element
            parser.nextToken();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("NEXT ARRAY NODE");

            BigDecimal first = parser.getDecimalValue();

            // Go to second value
            parser.nextToken();

            BigDecimal second = parser.getDecimalValue();

            // Skip inner end array element
            parser.nextToken();

            // Handle array item
            System.out.println("First: " + first.toString());
            System.out.println("Second: " + second.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Above program prints:

```
NEXT ARRAY NODE
First: -72.943068
Second: 45.842298

NEXT ARRAY NODE
First: -72.943075
Second: 45.841859
```

In my examples I used `Jackson` in `2.2.3` version.

Answer (score 0):

Create one json pojo mapper class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"coordinates"
})
public class Example {

@JsonProperty("coordinates")
private List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates = null;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

@JsonProperty("coordinates")
public List<List<List<Double>>> getCoordinates() {
return coordinates;
}

@JsonProperty("coordinates")
public void setCoordinates(List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates) {
this.coordinates = coordinates;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}

}
```

Then convert jsonString to pojo

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Example r = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Example.class);
```