# How to deserialise big JSON file (~300Mb)

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I want to parse a `JSON` file (size ~300Mb). I use `Jackson` library and `ObjectMapper`. Is it normal if i get memory problems?

The first time, i use `BufferedReader`, it crash application. Next, i use this library. How many time to parse and save into SQLite database, it's very long?

Comment: You need to use `Streaming API` to load your `JSON` partially, only a part which is needed to add one row. Take a look at: [Parsing JSON array to java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22361343/parsing-json-array-to-java-object), [Json processing with Jackson: Method #1/3: Reading and Writing Event Streams](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2009/01/entry_132.html), [Fastest way to parse JSON from String when format is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303782/fastest-way-to-parse-json-from-string-when-format-is-known)

Comment: The JSON DOM is not needed, hence @MichałZiober is right. If the data is very regular and the application need not be production quality even a manual parsing might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

### Jackson

You can mix `Streaming API` with regular `ObjectMapper`. Using these we can implement nice [Iterator](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/iterator) class. Using `URL` we can build stream and pass to our implementation. Example code could look like below:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //Just to make it work. Probably you should not do that!
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
        SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();

        URL url = new URL("https://data.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/vehicules-commercialises@public/download/?format=json&timezone=Europe/Berlin");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()))) {
            FieldsJsonIterator fieldsJsonIterator = new FieldsJsonIterator(reader);
            while (fieldsJsonIterator.hasNext()) {
                Fields fields = fieldsJsonIterator.next();
                System.out.println(fields);
                // Save object to DB
            }
        }
    }
}

class FieldsJsonIterator implements Iterator<Fields> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;
    private final JsonParser parser;

    public FieldsJsonIterator(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

        parser = mapper.getFactory().createParser(reader);
        skipStart();
    }

    private void skipStart() throws IOException {
        while (parser.currentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
            parser.nextToken();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        try {
            while (parser.currentToken() == null) {
                parser.nextToken();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

        return parser.currentToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fields next() {
        try {
            return mapper.readValue(parser, FieldsWrapper.class).fields;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    private static final class FieldsWrapper {
        public Fields fields;
    }
}

class Fields {

    private String cnit;

    @JsonProperty("puissance_maximale")
    private BigDecimal maximumPower;

    @JsonProperty("champ_v9")
    private String fieldV9;

    @JsonProperty("boite_de_vitesse")
    private String gearbox;

    // add other required properties

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Fields{cnit='MMB76K3BQJ41', maximumPower=110.0, fieldV9='70/220*2006/96EURO4', gearbox='A 5'}
Fields{cnit='M10MCDVPF15Z219', maximumPower=95.0, fieldV9='"715/2007*566/2011EURO5', gearbox='A 7'}
Fields{cnit='M10MCDVP027V654', maximumPower=150.0, fieldV9='715/2007*692/2008EURO5', gearbox='A 7'}
Fields{cnit='M10MCDVPG137264', maximumPower=120.0, fieldV9='715/2007*692/2008EURO5', gearbox='M 6'}
Fields{cnit='MVV4912QN718', maximumPower=210.0, fieldV9='null', gearbox='A 6'}
Fields{cnit='MMB76K3B2K88', maximumPower=110.0, fieldV9='null', gearbox='A 5'}
Fields{cnit='M10MCDVP012N140', maximumPower=80.0, fieldV9='70/220*2006/96EURO4', gearbox='M 6'}
Fields{cnit='MJN5423PU123', maximumPower=88.0, fieldV9='null', gearbox='M 6'}
Fields{cnit='M10MCDVP376T303', maximumPower=120.0, fieldV9='"715/2007*692/2008EURO5', gearbox='M 6'}
Fields{cnit='MMB53H3B5Z93', maximumPower=80.0, fieldV9='70/220*2006/96EURO4', gearbox='M 6'}
Fields{cnit='MPE1403E4834', maximumPower=81.0, fieldV9='null', gearbox='M 5'}
Fields{cnit='M10MCDVP018J905', maximumPower=110.0, fieldV9='70/220*2006/96EURO4', gearbox='M 6'}
Fields{cnit='M10MCDVPG112904', maximumPower=100.0, fieldV9='"715/2007*692/2008EURO5', gearbox='M 6'}
Fields{cnit='M10MCDVP015R723', maximumPower=110.0, fieldV9='70/220*2006/96EURO4', gearbox='A 5'}
...
```

### Gson

We can do the same using `Gson`. Example implementation could look like below:

```
class FieldsJsonIterator implements Iterator<Fields> {

    private final Gson mapper;
    private final JsonReader parser;

    public FieldsJsonIterator(Reader reader) throws IOException {
        mapper = new GsonBuilder().create();

        parser = mapper.newJsonReader(reader);
        skipStart();
    }

    private void skipStart() throws IOException {
        parser.beginArray();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        try {
            return parser.hasNext();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Fields next() {
        return ((FieldsWrapper) mapper.fromJson(parser, FieldsWrapper.class)).fields;
    }

    private static final class FieldsWrapper {
        public Fields fields;
    }
}

class Fields {

    private String cnit;

    @SerializedName("puissance_maximale")
    private BigDecimal maximumPower;

    @SerializedName("champ_v9")
    private String fieldV9;

    @SerializedName("boite_de_vitesse")
    private String gearbox;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Usage and output should be the same like it is for `Jackson`.

See also:

- [Best way to access nested JSON objects with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57997693/best-way-to-access-nested-json-objects-with-java)
- [Whats an easy way to totally ignore ssl with java url connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257455/whats-an-easy-way-to-totally-ignore-ssl-with-java-url-connections)

Comment: Thank you for your code, it's works fine and fast, i use Jackson library.

I see this class in your code, i'm interrested, where do you found this library for Android code:

   //Just to make it work. Probably you should not do that!
    SSLUtilities.trustAllHostnames();
    SSLUtilities.trustAllHttpsCertificates();

Of more, i would like to know if it's normal the parser JSON doesn't parse in order of json objects file (here "designation_commerciale"="LaFerrari" year="2014" it's the first element) ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user1400390, take a look on added links: "Whats an easy way to totally ignore ssl with java url connections?". You probably should not do that. I've added it because for my test it was required. Parser should parse all data in order.