# custom adapter and object cannot found

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, custom-adapter

I have a `MainActivity` that has a navigation drawer that calls a fragment to load a `ListView`. That `ListView` calls an xml to be the layout of the listitem. I am fetching the data from a webservice and wants to display 4 data on each list item. I created a `CustomAdapter` as mentioned in some tutorial to display data. My problem is I store the data to a `String` array and don't know how to put it in the object I created then pass to the `Adapter` then display

MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));


        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new SearchFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new SignInFragment();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
}
```

HOME FRAGMENT that calls the xml with the listview

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    /*Layout Variables*/
    protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    protected JSONArray blogPostData;
    protected TextView mTextView;

    /*Variables to be displayed*/
    protected String[] blogPostTitle;
    protected String[] blogPostDate;
    protected String[] blogPostAuthor;

    /*System Variables*/
    private ListView listView;
    private View rootView;
    articleListObject object;

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView        = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        listView        = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.article_list);
        mProgressBar    = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBarHome);
        mTextView       = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.networkCheck);

        mTextView.setText("Please Wait while we load the data!");
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArticleController articleController = new ArticleController(mListener);
        articleController.execute();


        return rootView;
    }

    public MyListener mListener = new MyListener(){

        @Override
        public void onComplete(JSONArray result)
        {
            blogPostData = result;
            updateArticleList();
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            /*List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(blogPostTitle));
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_listview_article, R.id.titleTV, stringList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);*/

            ArrayList<articleListObject> objects = new ArrayList<articleListObject>();
            articleListAdapter articleAdapter = new articleListAdapter(objects);
            listView.setAdapter(articleAdapter);

        }
    };

    protected void updateArticleList()
    {
        try
        {
            blogPostTitle       = new String[blogPostData.length()];
            blogPostDate        = new String[blogPostData.length()];
            blogPostAuthor      = new String[blogPostData.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < blogPostData.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonObject = blogPostData.getJSONObject(i);

                String title = jsonObject.getString("title");
                title = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();

                String date = jsonObject.getString("created_at");
                date = Html.fromHtml(date).toString();

                String author = jsonObject.getString("author");
                author = Html.fromHtml(author).toString();

                blogPostTitle[i]    = title;
                blogPostDate[i]     = date;
                blogPostAuthor[i]   = author;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the background async

```
public class ArticleController extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONArray> {

    MyListener mListener;

    public ArticleController(MyListener listenr) {
        mListener = listenr;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(Object... arg0)
    {
        String result = "No data available";
        JSONArray jsonResponse = null;

        try
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //TODO: URL ADDRESS for Articles.
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/****/public/webservices/post");
            /*httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");*/


            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("page", "1"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("limit","10"));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("category","0"));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

            /*InputStream inputStream = null;*/

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            result = sb.toString();
            jsonResponse = new JSONArray(result);

            Log.d("RESULT: ", result);

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "exception caught: ", e);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "exception caught: ", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "exception caught: ", e);
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result)
    {
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        homeFragment.blogPostData = result;
        mListener.onComplete(result);
    }
}
```

MY CustomAdapter

```
public class articleListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<articleListObject> objects;

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        TextView textView3;
    }

    public articleListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<articleListObject> objects) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    public articleListObject getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listview_article, null);
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleTV);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateTV);
            holder.textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.authorTV);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.textView1.setText(objects.get(position).getPostTitle());
        holder.textView2.setText(objects.get(position).getPostDate());
        holder.textView3.setText(objects.get(position).getPostAuthor());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

my constructor

```
public class articleListObject {

    /*Variables to be displayed*/
    protected String postTitle;
    protected String postDate;
    protected String postAuthor;

    public articleListObject(String postTitle, String postDate, String postAuthor) {

        this.postTitle  = postTitle;
        this.postDate   = postDate;
        this.postAuthor = postAuthor;
    }
    public String getPostTitle() {
        return postTitle;
    }
    public String getPostDate() {
        return postDate;
    }
    public String getPostAuthor() {
        return postAuthor;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you need to convert your JsonArray response to a String (in your Asyntask) You could use some library (like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1396087/1612432)

Comment: I already converted them. What I want is to send them to the listView

Comment: Do you have some error in the LogCat? What is the layout for each row in the ListView?