# Converting a String to array of JSON objects and parsing those

Tags: java, json, string

I have a string in the format like this

```
[{name:"abc",test:"123",jack:{tret:"abc",cold:"yes"},killer:"yes"},{name:"pqr",test:"456",jack:{tret:"hg",cold:"No"},killer:"No"}]
```

I know that this is an array of `JSON` objects.How do I convert this so?

As of now i am just using split and removing all the commas and other things from the string and storing in an array.Is there any better way to do so?

Comment: One would use a JSON parser.  You have your choice of about 20 different ones, listed at json.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a JSON library is definitely the way to go, but I might suggest one that's being actively developed such as [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).  Both have extensive documentation and examples.

Answer (score 2):

Use the https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/ library for handling JSON.

Here is a sample code:

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse("{\"name\":\"MyNode\", \"width\":200, \"height\":100}");
System.out.println("name=" + json.get("name"));
System.out.println("width=" + json.get("width"));
```

Please refer to this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java) for more answers in this matter.

Comment: If you think this answer your question, please check the green sign below the arrows on the left-side of the question.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library from Google

```
JsonElement parse = (new JsonParser()).parse(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jackson library and further you can go through this for parsing http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-tree-model-example/