# get value from a JSONObject

Tags: java, parsing, json

I have a  JSONObject.

```js
{
  "_shards":{
      "total":251,
      "failed":0,
      "successful":251
   },
   "hits":{
      "hits":[

      ],
      "total":7775532,
      "max_score":0
   },
   "took":517,
   "timed_out":false,
   "facets":{
      "terms":{
         "total":2287,
         "other":0,
         "terms":[
            {
               "count":2268,
               "term":"contact"
            },
            {
               "count":19,
               "term":""
            }
         ],
         "_type":"terms",
         "missing":424
      }
   }
}
```

I want to get the value of hits.total which here is 7775532. 
How can I get that ? Is there some function that can help ? I am using Java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a JSON string to object in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java)

Comment: Java also has a default library you can use, which is pointed out in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java) answer

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonObject.getJSONObject("hits").get("total")
```

Comment: how to do that if that is a List ??

Comment: And i want the result as a String

Comment: what list? If you want the result as a String, use `getString("total")`