# Passing Object into Method/Function

Tags: string

This is my method/function:

```
public static Object testFunction (String GoesHere)
```

I'm not sure how to reference the object as I've checked its syntax and seems to be written correctly, but it does not have a name. Also, it's of type and the method/function is expecting a string. Thanks so much

Comment: Similar Question ON SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java

Comment: @ArunKumar Thank you, but I cannot use external libraries

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in Json format, you can just refer that as a Json String

```
String jsonString =  JSONObject.escape(yourRawString);
```

The type of JSONObject is  `org.json.simple.JSONObject`

Then pass it to `testFunction(jsonString)`

Comment: Can you give me an example of setting yourRawString to some JSON code? Thanks, I've tried that and it's giving me errors

Comment: @HaroldFinch You have to escape the quotes

Comment: Yes I tried not using quotes and I'm getting an error. Here's a screenshot: http://imgur.com/UwDmbCT

Comment: I am started with an '{'. I also don't want everything to be on the same line because I want to parse this later and will take advantage of the fact it has new lines.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can use JsonObject. This is the best way to create the json object and use.

```
JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("radio","on");
```

If you want String after creating just call this method.

```
jsonObject.toString();
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but it says cannot resolve JSONObject. I tried this but it's not working: import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Comment: Yes you should import the package.Check if you have that package otherwise download and use it.@HaroldFinch

Comment: Hi thanks I successfully imported that, but now it's saying cannot resolve symbol "put"