# How to populate dynamically scrollview with JSON data

Tags: android, arrays, json, scrollview

I'm still new to android, and i'm trying to create something like this dynamically:
[scrollview with imagebuttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWDAN.jpg)

On this example i have it hardcoded in xml and i have no idea how to do it dynamically. Can you guys help with with a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `CardView` instead of `scrollview`.
[Deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java) your Json into object list and then [create adapter for Cardview](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to display a list of items instead of using ScrollView. You have to use a RecyclerView with an adapter for data.

Check this training on Android Developers portal:
http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html