# How to convert JsonObject to Java Object and use it in my Selenium code

Tags: json, selenium-webdriver

please help me with below condition :-convert JsonObject to Java Object and use it in your Selenium

Comment: Can you give more info?

Comment: what is the purpose of converting json to javaobject and use it further?

Comment: i am doing API automation

Answer (score 2):

Firstly You have not posted your code therefore where i understood check following

[Go through this link](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/06/json-in-java-using-gson.html)

you can use this also [Using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395551/convert-a-json-string-to-object-in-java)

`MyObject ob = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, MyObject.class);`